# How to quantify overlap between three periods?

Tags: r, function, date, overlap

I am writing a function to calculate the duration of overlap between three periods, but I am having trouble in finding out how to efficiently program this, so hopefully someone can help me out.

I have a dataset of people who have been followed over time. The starting date, and also the time spent in the study differs between the participants. For each participant, I would like to calculate how many days they were in the study in a specific year and in which 5-year age category that was. For example, if someone was in the study from 01-01-2000 to 01-06-2001, and he was born on 15-06-1965, he would contribute 166 days to the 30-34 year age category in 2000, 200 days in the 35-39 year age category in 2000 and 151 days in to the 35-39 year age category in 2001, while he spent 0 days in all other categories.

In other words: I would like to quantify the overlap between these periods:

A = entering study to ending study 
    (varies among participants, but fixed value within participant)

B = begin specific year to end specific year 
    (same among participants, varies within participant)

C = entering specific 5-yr age category to exiting specific 5-yr age category
    (varies among participants, varies within participant)

My data looks something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(lapply(
       data.frame("Birth"=c("1965-06-15","1960-02-01","1952-05-02"),
                  "Begin"=c("2000-01-01","2003-08-14","2007-12-05"),
                  "End"=c("2001-06-01","2006-10-24","2012-03-01")),as.Date))
```

Thus far, I came up with this, but now do not know how to proceed (or whether I should take a totally different approach)…

```
spec.fu <- function(years,birth,begin,end,age.cat,data){

  birth <- data[,birth]
  start.A <- data[,begin]
  end.A <- data[,end]

  for (i in years){
    start.B <- as.Date(paste(i,"01-01",sep="-")) 
    end.B <- as.Date(paste(i+1,"01-01",sep="-")) 

    for (j in age.cat){
      start.C <- paste((as.numeric(format(birth, "%Y"))+j), 
                        format(birth,"%m-%d"), sep="-")
      end.C <- paste((as.numeric(format(birth, "%Y"))+j+5), 
                      format(birth,"%m-%d"), sep="-")

      result <- ?????

      data[,ncol(data)+?????] <- result
      colnames(data)[ncol(data)+?????] <- paste("fu",j,"in",i,sep="")
      }
  } 
  return(data)
}
```

And use it like this:

```
 newdata <- spec.fu(years=2000:2001,birth="Birth",begin="Begin",
                    end="End",age.cat=seq(30,35,5),data=dat)
```

So, in this case, I want to make 2 (no. of age categories) * 2 (no. of years) = 4 new columns for each participant, each containing the no. of days that someone has spent in the study in that specific category (e.g. in age category 30-34 in 2001).

Hopefully I was able to clearly explain my problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to look at the `?survSplit` function in the `eha` package. `df <- survSplit(dat, cut=as.Date(paste(1950:2013, "01", "01", sep="-")), end="End", start="Birth", event="ev",id="id")`

Comment: @shadow Thanks, survSplit looks really useful. I found a solution without using it though (see below), but perhaps using survSplit (or code based on it) could be more efficient/concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (see below). The code looks rather cumbersome though, so can probably be made more efficient. Any advise is welcome!

```
spec.fu <- function(years,birth,begin,end,age.cat,data){

  birth <- data[,birth]
  start.A <- data[,begin]
  end.A <- data[,end]

  if (any(sapply(c(birth,start.A,end.A),FUN=function(x) class(x)!="Date"))) {
    stop("'birth', 'begin' and 'end' must be of class 'Date''") }

  # ifelse-function that saves Date class in vectors     
  # (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963)
  safe.ifelse <- function(cond, yes, no) {
                          structure(ifelse(cond, yes, no), class = class(yes))}

  for (i in years){
    start.B <- rep(as.Date(paste(i,"01-01",sep="-")),nrow(data))
    end.B <- rep(as.Date(paste(i+1,"01-01",sep="-")),nrow(data))

    start.AB <- safe.ifelse((start.A <= end.B & start.B <= end.A) &  
                             start.A >= start.B, start.A,
                 safe.ifelse((start.A <= end.B & start.B <= end.A) &  
                              start.B >= start.A, start.B,
                                    as.Date("1000-01-01"))) 
 #in latter case overlap is zero, but a Date is required later on

    end.AB <- safe.ifelse((start.A <= end.B & start.B <= end.A) &  
                           end.A <= end.B, end.A,
               safe.ifelse((start.A <= end.B & start.B <= end.A) &  
                           end.B <= end.A, end.B,
                                  as.Date("1000-01-01"))) 

    for (j in age.cat){
      start.C <- safe.ifelse(format(birth,"%m")=="02" & format(birth,
                             "%d")=="29", 
                             as.Date(paste((as.numeric(format(birth, 
                                     "%Y"))+j),format(birth,"%m"),
                                     "28", sep="-")),
                             as.Date(paste((as.numeric(format(birth, 
                                     "%Y"))+j), format(birth,"%m-%d"), 
                                     sep="-")))
      end.C <- safe.ifelse(format(birth,"%m")=="02" & format(birth,
                           "%d")=="29",
                           as.Date(paste((as.numeric(format(birth, 
                                   "%Y"))+j+5),format(birth,"%m"),
                                   "28", sep="-")),
                           as.Date(paste((as.numeric(format(birth, 
                                   "%Y"))+j+5),format(birth,"%m-%d"), 
                                   sep="-")))
      start.ABC <- safe.ifelse((start.AB <= end.C & start.C <= end.AB) & 
                                start.AB >= start.C, start.AB,
                   safe.ifelse((start.AB <= end.C & start.C <= end.AB) & 
                                start.C >= start.AB, start.C,
                                       as.Date("1000-01-01")))

      end.ABC <- safe.ifelse((start.AB <= end.C & start.C <= end.AB) & 
                              end.AB <= end.C, end.AB,
                  safe.ifelse((start.AB <= end.C & start.C <= end.AB) & 
                              end.C <= end.AB, end.C,
                                       as.Date("1000-01-01")))

      result <- as.numeric(difftime(end.ABC,start.ABC,units="days"))

      data <- cbind(data,result)
      colnames(data) <- c(colnames(data)[1:(ncol(data)-1)],
                      paste("fu",j,"in",i,sep=""))
      }
    } 
  return(data)
}
```

The function can be used as follows:

```
newdata <- spec.fu(years=2000:2001,birth="Birth",begin="Begin",
                   end="End",age.cat=seq(30,35,5),data=dat)
```

Which gives the following result (new columns 4:7):

```
> newdata
       Birth      Begin        End fu30in2000 fu35in2000 fu30in2001 fu35in2001
1 1965-06-15 2000-01-01 2001-06-01        166        200          0        151
2 1960-02-01 2003-08-14 2006-10-24          0          0          0          0
3 1952-05-02 2007-12-05 2012-03-01          0          0          0          0
```

UPDATE (August 6 2013): Fixed bug in function that caused NA's when date of birth was on leap day.