# unable to retrieve POSIXct from numeric format after ifelse statement (R)

Tags: r, if-statement, posixct

I have a table like so:

```
dtab<-data.table(Arr.Dep=c("A","D"),
       time=c("2017-05-01 04:50:00","2017-05-01 04:55:00"))

dtab[,time:=parse_date_time(dtab$time, c("%y-%m-%d %H:%M%S"))]
```

Operations on the date and time column seem successful:

```
dtab[,time2:=time+2]
```

But if I try to run an ifelse statement, the POSIXct format goes back to numeric and I seem to be unable to bring it back to date and time.

```
dtab[,time3:=ifelse(dtab[,Arr.Dep]=="A",dtab[,time]+2,"hello")]
```

I saw the issue has already been raised:
[R- date time variable loses format after ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019820/r-date-time-variable-loses-format-after-ifelse)

Unfortunately it's not of great help to me, as when I try to follow the example - adding 2 seconds rather than replacing with NA as in the OP -, I hit an error anyway.
Any help?

Comment: If your third argument in `ifelse` would also be a date, e.g. `if_else(Arr.Dep =="A", time +2, time)`, then the `dplyr` function `if_else` solves the problem. But this function is just useable, if the second and third argument have the same type, e.g. `date`.

Comment: Yes! It works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use library(lubridate) and add time dtab$time2 <- dtab$time2 + seconds(2). With this method, the format does not change.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work, POSIXct format goes back to numeric. I guess the problem stems from the operations performed internally with the ifelse operator.