# R sapply vs apply vs lapply + as.data.frame

Tags: r, date, plyr, apply, lapply

I'm working with some `Date` columns and trying to cleanse for obviously incorrect dates.  I've written a function using the `safe.ifelse` function mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects).

Here's my toy data set:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:25
    , month1 = seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2014-01-01'), by = 'month'  )
    , month2 = seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2014-01-01'), by = 'month'  )
    , month3 = seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2014-01-01'), by = 'month'  )
    , letter1 = letters[1:25]
    )
```

This works fine for a single column:

```
df1$month1 <- safe.ifelse(df1$month1 > as.Date('2013-10-01'), as.Date('2013-10-01'), df1$month1)
```

As I have multiple columns I'd like to use a function and apply to take care of all `Date` columns at once:

```
capDate <- function(x){
today1 <- Sys.Date()
    safe.ifelse <- function(cond, yes, no){ class.y <- class(yes)
                                  X <- ifelse(cond,yes,no)
                                  class(X) <-class.y; return(X)}

    x <- safe.ifelse(as.Date(x) > as.Date(today1), as.Date(today1), as.Date(x))
 }
```

However when I try to use `sapply()`

```
df1[,dateCols1] <- sapply(df1[,dateCols1], capDate)
```

or `apply()`

```
df1[,dateCols1] <- apply(df1[,dateCols1],2, capDate))
```

the `Date` columns lose their `Date` formatting.  The only way I've found to get around this is by using `lapply()` and then converting back to a `data.frame()`.  Can anyone explain this?

```
df1[,dateCols1] <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1[,dateCols1], capDate))
```

Comment: Both convert to a matrix or an array. Use `lapply` and then `do.call( data.frame , output )` on the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `sapply` and `apply` convert the result to matrices.  `as.data.frame(lapply(...))` is a safe way to loop over data frame columns.

```
as.data.frame(
  lapply(
    df1, 
    function(column) 
    {
      if(inherits(column, "Date")) 
      {
        pmin(column, Sys.Date())
      } else column
    }
  )
)
```

---

It's a little cleaner with `ddply` from `plyr`.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(
  df1, 
  .(id), 
  colwise(
    function(column) 
    {
      if(inherits(column, "Date")) 
      { 
        pmin(column, Sys.Date()) 
      } else column
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: +1 for making me read `as.data.frame` to realise you don't need `do.call( data.frame , ... )`