# sapply and apply give different results with is.character()

Tags: r, character, apply

I was trying to convert tolower the features of my dataframe that are of type character and found out this post:
[tolower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516593/convert-from-lowercase-to-uppercase-all-values-in-all-character-variables-in-dat)
I build up a function to do so on several data.frames and finally discovered that all my features were treated as characters!

```
mytolower <- function(p_vector){
  if (is.character(p_vector)) return(tolower(iconv(enc2utf8(p_vector), sub = "byte")))
  else return(p_vector)
}
for (df in c("train", "test")) as.data.frame(apply(get(df), 2, function(x) mytolower(x)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Looking better on Stackoverflow, I found out this 2nd post that partially solved the issue by using lapply, but which curiously suggest that apply and sapply work in a similar way
[lapply rather than apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515692/r-sapply-vs-apply-vs-lapply-as-data-frame)
Thus, I finally build up this example that basically illustrate my trouble:

```
train <- data.frame(v1=1:3, v2=c("a","b","c"), v3=11:13, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(train)
apply(train, 2, function(x) is.character(x)) #wrong
lapply(train, function(x) is.character(x)) #right
sapply(train, function(x) is.character(x)) #right
sapply(train, is.character) #right
```

While apply will consider all features as being "character", lapply or sapply will be able to distinguish numerical and character features. Why is it so ? Is there a way to make apply find the right answer ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before `is.character()` is applied, `train` is first coerced to a matrix. Since a matrix holds only objects of a single type, all elements become character strings.

From the help file for `apply()`:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.

I would suggest using the `mutate_if()` function from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_if(train, is.character, toupper)

#    v1 v2 v3
#    1  1  A 11
#    2  2  B 12
#    3  3  C 13
```

Answer (score 0):

apply function needs a matrix or array as it's input and it force converts the data frame you are feeding it and that as.matrix() conversion converts all of the array to a character array since all columns are coming out to be of character type.