# How to recursively rename a list based on its list items

Tags: r, jstreer

I'd like to recursively rename (or name, as those items are currently unnamed) a `list()` based on its items (here `text`). There are several similar questions, however I haven't found one with a list structure as follows and I can't seem to find a general recursive approach to solve this.

The example data comes from [here](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR/blob/master/inst/examples/contextMenu/global.R):

```
nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "RootA",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildA1"
      ),
      list(
        text = "ChildA2"
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = "RootB",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildB1"
      ),
      list(
        text = "ChildB2"
      )
    )
  )
)
# hard coded solution:
names(nodes) <- c(nodes[[1]]$text, nodes[[2]]$text)
names(nodes[[1]]$children) <- c(nodes[[1]]$children[[1]]$text, nodes[[1]]$children[[2]]$text)
names(nodes[[2]]$children) <- c(nodes[[2]]$children[[1]]$text, nodes[[2]]$children[[2]]$text)
str(nodes)
```

Expected output:

```
List of 2
 $ RootA:List of 2
  ..$ text    : chr "RootA"
  ..$ children:List of 2
  .. ..$ ChildA1:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildA1"
  .. ..$ ChildA2:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildA2"
 $ RootB:List of 2
  ..$ text    : chr "RootB"
  ..$ children:List of 2
  .. ..$ ChildB1:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildB1"
  .. ..$ ChildB2:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildB2"
```

---

**Edit:** I just benchmarked the three answer given on my system. The function provided by @knitz3 seems to be the fastest. Thanks everyone - I learned a lot.

```
Unit: microseconds
                  expr     min        lq     mean   median        uq     max neval
 list_rename_recursive  46.200   64.7010  458.389   79.601   95.2510 36040.6   100
           modify_tree 886.102 1929.4005 2787.664 2302.801 2779.1010 18778.5   100
            names_text 101.001  207.8015  575.603  246.852  305.9505 30270.8   100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was fun. I went for something very interpretable. This function loops through every item of the list provided, and calls on itself if an item is itself another list. Should be able to handle unnamed list items as well.

```r
list_rename_recursive <- function(x) {

    # If not a list, return the item
    if (!is.list(x)) {

        return(x)

    } else {

        # If a list, iterate through the items of the list
        for (i in seq_along(x)) {

            # If the list item i itself is a list, call
            # the function again. The list item is updated
            # with the returned value with proper name
            # $text if found
            if (is.list(x[[i]])) {

                name_item <- NA
                if (!is.null(x[[i]]$text)) name_item <- x[[i]]$text
                x[[i]] <- list_rename_recursive(x[[i]])
                if (!is.na(name_item)) names(x)[i] <- name_item

            }

        }

        return(x)

    }

}

nodes_new <- list_rename_recursive(nodes)
str(nodes_new)
```

```r
List of 2
 $ RootA:List of 2
  ..$ text    : chr "RootA"
  ..$ children:List of 2
  .. ..$ ChildA1:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildA1"
  .. ..$ ChildA2:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildA2"
 $ RootB:List of 2
  ..$ text    : chr "RootB"
  ..$ children:List of 2
  .. ..$ ChildB1:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildB1"
  .. ..$ ChildB2:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildB2"
```

Answer (score 9):

We can use [`purrr:modify_tree()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/modify_tree.html).

> `modify_tree()` allows you to recursively modify a list, supplying functions that either modify each leaf or each node (or both).

We can check if each node has a field called `"text"` and if so use that to `setNames()` of that node.

```r
l  <- nodes |>
    purrr::modify_tree(
        pre = \(x) {
            if ("text" %in% sapply(x, \(l) names(l))) {
                return(setNames(x, sapply(x, \(l) l$text)))
            }
            x
        }
    )
```

The definition of the `pre` parameter is:

> `pre`, `post` Functions applied to each node. `pre` is applied on the way "down", i.e. before the leaves are transformed with `leaf`, while `post` is applied on the way "up", i.e. after the leaves are transformed.

We are not using a `leaf` function here so we could equally use `post` and the output would be identical.

Incidentally, I've used `sapply()` for illustrative purposes but as this can sometimes return an `array` or `matrix`, it's generally [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515692/r-sapply-vs-apply-vs-lapply-as-data-frame) to use `unlist(lapply())`.

##### Output

R doesn't print lists like these very nicely, so here it is as a json:

```r
jsonlite::toJSON(l, pretty = TRUE)
{
  "RootA": {
    "text": ["RootA"],
    "children": {
      "ChildA1": {
        "text": ["ChildA1"]
      },
      "ChildA2": {
        "text": ["ChildA2"]
      }
    }
  },
  "RootB": {
    "text": ["RootB"],
    "children": {
      "ChildB1": {
        "text": ["ChildB1"]
      },
      "ChildB2": {
        "text": ["ChildB2"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And just to confirm this is the same as the hardcoded output:

```r
all(
    names(l) == c(l[[1]]$text, l[[2]]$text),
    names(l[[1]]$children) == c(l[[1]]$children[[1]]$text, l[[1]]$children[[2]]$text),
    names(l[[2]]$children) == c(l[[2]]$children[[1]]$text, l[[2]]$children[[2]]$text)
) # TRUE
```

Answer (score 8):

This recursive function seems to work

```
names_text <- function(x) {
  if (is.list(x)) {
    if (is.null(names(x))) {
      nn <- sapply(x, function(x) if(is.list(x) & "text" %in% names(x)) x[["text"]])
      x <- lapply(x, names_text)
      setNames(x, nn)
    } else {
      lapply(x, names_text)
    }
  } else {
    x
  }
}
```

Testing with the sample data we get

```
names_text(nodes) |> str()
List of 2
 $ RootA:List of 2
  ..$ text    : chr "RootA"
  ..$ children:List of 2
  .. ..$ ChildA1:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildA1"
  .. ..$ ChildA2:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildA2"
 $ RootB:List of 2
  ..$ text    : chr "RootB"
  ..$ children:List of 2
  .. ..$ ChildB1:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildB1"
  .. ..$ ChildB2:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: chr "ChildB2"
```

The idea is we look for unnamed lists, and then try to extract the "text" value from each child in that list and use that as the names.

There's not a lot of error handling here and there are a lot of assumptions about the data structure, but it works with the test data.