# Delete list items based on its nested content

Tags: r, jstreer

This is basically a spin-off of my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77267022/16984874).

Taking into account the following example data, I'd like to recursively delete all `children` (and parents which have no more children) which contain the item `selected = FALSE` or vice versa copy all `children` which contain the item `selected = TRUE` while maintaining the list structure (please see the list `expected_output`).

My attempts so far fail:

```
# data --------------------------------------------------------------------
nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "RootA",
    state = list(loaded = TRUE, opened = TRUE, selected = TRUE, disabled = FALSE),
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildA1",
        state = list(loaded = TRUE, opened = TRUE, selected = TRUE, disabled = FALSE)
      ),
      list(
        text = "ChildA2",
        state = list(loaded = TRUE, opened = TRUE, selected = FALSE, disabled = FALSE)
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = "RootB",
    state = list(loaded = TRUE, opened = TRUE, selected = FALSE, disabled = FALSE),
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildB1",
        state = list(loaded = TRUE, opened = TRUE, selected = FALSE, disabled = FALSE)
      ),
      list(
        text = "ChildB2",
        state = list(loaded = TRUE, opened = TRUE, selected = FALSE, disabled = FALSE)
      )
    )
  )
)

# Error in x[[i]] : subscript out of bounds -------------------------------
delete_unselected_nodes <- function(x) {
  y <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    value <- x[[i]]
    if("state" %in% names(x)){
      if(x[["state"]][["selected"]] == TRUE) {
        y <- c(y, x[[i]]) 
      }
    } else {
      x[[i]] <- delete_unselected_nodes(value)
    }
  }
}

delete_unselected_nodes(nodes)

# expected output ---------------------------------------------------------
expected_output <- list(
  list(
    text = "RootA",
    state = list(loaded = TRUE, opened = TRUE, selected = TRUE, disabled = FALSE),
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildA1",
        state = list(loaded = TRUE, opened = TRUE, selected = TRUE, disabled = FALSE)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the functionality from purrr to deal with lists and define some (predicate) functions to keep it tidy:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lobstr)

# define sample data ------------------------------------------------------

# ...

# define functions --------------------------------------------------------

# filter list of children to keep only where selected == TRUE
delete_unselected_children <- function(children_list) {
  keep(
    children_list,
    .p = \(x) x$state$selected)
}

# replace list element "children" of root with filtered list of children
delete_from_root <- function(root) {
  modify_in(
    root,
    .where = list("children"),
    .f = delete_unselected_children
  )
}

# define predicate function to drop roots without children
has_no_children <- function(root) {
  is_empty(root$children)
}


# apply -------------------------------------------------------------------

result <- nodes |> 
  map(delete_from_root) |> 
  discard(has_no_children)

lobstr::tree(result)
#> <list>
#> └─<list>
#>   ├─text: "RootA"
#>   ├─state: <list>
#>   │ ├─loaded: TRUE
#>   │ ├─opened: TRUE
#>   │ ├─selected: TRUE
#>   │ └─disabled: FALSE
#>   └─children: <list>
#>     └─<list>
#>       ├─text: "ChildA1"
#>       └─state: <list>
#>         ├─loaded: TRUE
#>         ├─opened: TRUE
#>         ├─selected: TRUE
#>         └─disabled: FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>