# Fast way to replace all blanks with NA in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have a large data.table object (1M rows and 220 columns) and I want to replace all blanks ('') with NA. I found a solution in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172111/change-the-blank-cells-to-na), but it's extremely slow for my data table (takes already over 15mins) 
Example from the other post:

```
 data = data.frame(cats=rep(c('', ' ', 'meow'),1e6),
                   dogs=rep(c("woof", " ", NA),1e6))
 system.time(x<-apply(data, 2, function(x) gsub("^$|^ $", NA, x)))
```

Is there a more data.table fast way to achieve this?

Indeed the provided data does not look much like the original data, it was just to give an example. The following subset of my real data gives the CharToDate(x) error:

```
DT <- data.table(ID=c(10),DEFAULT_DATE=as.Date("2012-07-31"),value='')
system.time(DT[DT=='']<-NA)
```

Comment: I think you've made a mistake on populating your data in `rep(dogs=c("woof...`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's probably the generic `data.table` way of doing this. I'm also going to use your regex which handles several types of blanks (I havn't seen other answers doing this). You probably shouldn't run this over *all* your columns rather only over the `factor` or `character` ones, because other classes won't accept blank values.

For `factor`s

```
indx <- which(sapply(data, is.factor))
for (j in indx) set(data, i = grep("^$|^ $", data[[j]]), j = j, value = NA_integer_)
```

For `character`s

```
indx2 <- which(sapply(data, is.character)) 
for (j in indx2) set(data, i = grep("^$|^ $", data[[j]]), j = j, value = NA_character_)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (again) @David. Worked in 4.79 seconds!

Comment: now I get the NA values as <NA> which are not recognized by the `is.na()` function. If I change it to `system.time(for (j in indx) set(data, i = grep("^$|^ $", data[[j]]), j = j, value = NA))` it fails, what you probably also encountered? Is there a way of setting the values to the 'standard' NA?

Comment: Isn't it strange that the NA_character is recognized in the `is.na(NA_character_)` but not if I use this function for the data.table where I just replaced blanks with that NA_character_:
`data[is.na(DEFAULT_DATE)]->dataNA`. Or am I missing something? PS. see edit in Question for the new data.

Comment: Ok, try this `indx <- which(sapply(data, is.factor));
system.time(for (j in indx) set(data, i = grep("^$|^ $", data[[j]]), j = j, value = NA_integer_));
indx2 <- which(sapply(data, is.character));
system.time(for (j in indx2) set(data, i = grep("^$|^ $", data[[j]]), j = j, value = NA_character_))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't know why but I'm testing `data[data=='']<-NA` versus `for (j in indx2) set(data, i = grep("^$|^ $", data[[j]]), j = j, value = NA_character_)` with `microbenchmark` package and tells me first option is much faster.

Comment: @OriolPrat you are comparing apples with oranges. Running regex vs doing an exact match has nothing to do with data.table. The point of this answer was to show how to use OPs regex using correct data.table syntax. In this case regex wasn't probably needed in the first place. Although `data[data=='']<-NA` doesn't replace the `" "` values.

Answer (score 8):

Use this approach:

```
system.time(data[data==''|data==' ']<-NA)
  user  system elapsed 
  1.47    0.19    1.66 

system.time(y<-apply(data, 2, function(x) gsub("^$|^ $", NA, x)))
  user  system elapsed 
  3.41    0.20    3.64
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the `Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` error. Will try to solve it and come back if it works as expected!

Comment: You can't solve this with just `''` as you have different types of blanks in the data.

Comment: ?? which data are you using? not the set of data of your example I guess ;)

Comment: well maybe the OP wants to keep ' '. @Tim, can you give more details on this?

Comment: OP used a regex in order to remove them `gsub("^$|^ $", NA, x)` (which is pretty much self explanatory)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you had mistake while populating your data, below is the solution using data.table which you used in tag.

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table(cats=rep(c('', ' ', 'meow'),1000000),dogs=rep(c("woof", " ", NA),1000000))
system.time(data[cats=='', cats := NA][dogs=='', dogs := NA])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.056   0.000   0.059
```

If you have a lot of column see David's comment.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few different ways to do this, I found the quickest and simplest option to be:

```
data[data==""] <- NA
```