# linear models with contrasts including every possible comparison

Tags: r, lm, categorical-data

Does anyone know if it is possible to use `lmFit` or `lm` in R to calculate a linear model with categorical variables while including all possible comparisons between the categories? For example in the test data created here:

```
set.seed(25)
f <- gl(n = 3, k = 20, labels = c("control", "low", "high"))
mat <- model.matrix(~f, data = data.frame(f = f))
beta <- c(12, 3, 6)  #these are the simulated regression coefficient
y <- rnorm(n = 60, mean = mat %*% beta, sd = 2)
m <- lm(y ~ f)
```

I get the summary:

```
summary(m)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ f)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.3505 -1.6114  0.1608  1.1615  5.2010 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  11.4976     0.4629  24.840  < 2e-16 ***
flow          3.0370     0.6546   4.639 2.09e-05 ***
fhigh         6.1630     0.6546   9.415 3.27e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.07 on 57 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6086,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5949 
F-statistic: 44.32 on 2 and 57 DF,  p-value: 2.446e-12
```

which is because the contrasts term ("contr.treatment") compares "high" to "control" and "low" to "control".

Is it possible to get also the comparison between "high" and "low"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `aov` instead of `lm`, you can use the `TukeyHSD` function from the `stats` package:

```
fit <- aov(y ~ f)
TukeyHSD(fit)
#   Tukey multiple comparisons of means
#     95% family-wise confidence level

# Fit: aov(formula = y ~ f)

# $f
#                  diff      lwr      upr    p adj
# low-control  3.036957 1.461707 4.612207 6.15e-05
# high-control 6.163009 4.587759 7.738259 0.00e+00
# high-low     3.126052 1.550802 4.701302 3.81e-05
```

If you want to use an `lm` object, you can use the `TukeyHSD` function from the `mosaic` package:

```
library(mosaic)
TukeyHSD(m)
```

Or, as @ben-bolker suggests,

```
library(emmeans)
e1 <- emmeans(m, specs = "f")
pairs(e1)
#  contrast        estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
#  control - low  -3.036957 0.6546036 57  -4.639  0.0001
#  control - high -6.163009 0.6546036 57  -9.415  <.0001
#  low - high     -3.126052 0.6546036 57  -4.775  <.0001

# P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

---

With `lmFit`:

```
library(limma)
design <- model.matrix(~0 + f)
colnames(design) <- levels(f)
fit <- lmFit(y, design)
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(control-low, control-high, low-high,
                                 levels = design)
fit2 <- contrasts.fit(fit, contrast.matrix)
fit2 <- eBayes(fit2)
round(t(rbind(fit2$coefficients, fit2$t, fit2$p.value)), 5)
#                    [,1]     [,2]  [,3]
# control - low  -3.03696 -4.63938 2e-05
# control - high -6.16301 -9.41487 0e+00
# low - high     -3.12605 -4.77549 1e-05
```

Also see [Multiple t-test comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305742/multiple-t-test-comparisons) for more information.

Comment: What about if I use lmFit?