# How to replace blank values in character column with "NA" in R dataset?

Tags: r

I have dataset with Named "Missing_Values".
In that there is column named "city" and some of rows are blank i.e they don't have any city listed there. How can I replace blank values with "NA" in R lang.?

It is like -

```
ID   Name  Age
1     ram   34
2           46
3    shyam  56
4           87
```

[image]

Comment: Image is attached . Kindly have a look

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172111/change-the-blank-cells-to-na

Comment: Please share data in a reproducible and copy&paste-able format (using e.g. `dput`). Screenshots are not useful because we can't (easily) extract data/code from an image.

Comment: The image you showed is from Excel, but your requesting an R solution. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and reformat accordingly

Comment: It is the snapshot of datatable. .CSV file is imported in R.

Comment: It is like - 
ID   Name  Age
1     ram      34
2                 46
3     shyam  56
4                  87

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this data:

```
Missing_Values <- data.frame(State = sample(c("", 1:9), 10, T), 
                             City = sample(c("", letters[1:9]), 10, T))
```

If it's only the city column you can do this:

```
Missing_Values$City[Missing_Values$City==""] <- NA
```

If it's for all columns:

```
Missing_Values[Missing_Values==''] <- NA
```