# How to remove blank cells from dataframe?

Tags: r

I have the attached csv file. How can I fill the blank cells with NA or remove them?

I have tried following codes from [Change the Blank Cells to "NA"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172111/change-the-blank-cells-to-na#) but nothing happens.

```
sm2=read.csv('sample_info_2.csv',header=T, na.strings=" ")
sm3 <- sm2 %>% mutate_all(na_if,"")
sm3=sm2[complete.cases(sm2),]
```

[image]
I want to remove the blank cells or fill them with NA. Any help? Best, Zillur

Comment: May be you have `""` instead of `NA` use `read.csv('sample_info_2.csv',header=T, na.strings=c(" ", ""))` and then with `complete.cases` should work

Comment: If akrun's comment or my answer do not address your issue, however, please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @akrun's comment is right (and this really should be handled on data-import if possible), but if you need to handle it post-import then it might be missing one point: since your `mutate_all(na_if, "")` did not work, you have fields that are whitespace-only with one *or more* whitespace characters. If all of these fields have the same amount of whitespace, then perhaps

```r
sm2 %>% mutate_all(na_if, " ") # or "  " or "   " ...
```

will work, but it is inflexible. A more accommodating technique might be:

```r
sm2 %>% mutate_if(is.character, ~ if_else(grepl("\\S", .), ., NA_character_))
```

which does two things:

1. I do not assume that all of your columns are strings, so `mutate_if(is.character, ...)` instead of `mutate_all`, perhaps minor; and
2. `grepl("\\S", .)` will return `TRUE` for all elements of a vector that have one (or more) non-whitespace character, and the `if_else` handles replacement when false. (It might also be feasible to picture this as `nzchar(gsub("\\s", "", .))` which first removes all whitespace and then returns true for string length greater than 0.)

Answer (score 1):

To fill all of the blanks with NA you need to cover more options with the na.strings argument.
Here is a dummy example that demonstrates how to fill the blanks in numeric and string columns.

```
col1 <- rep(c(1,2,"",3), 3)
col2 <- rep(c(2,3,"",4), 3)
col3 <- rep(c("a","","b","c"), 3)
my_df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

csv_file_path <- paste0(getwd(), "/", "data_with_gaps.csv")
write.csv(my_df, csv_file_path, row.names = FALSE)

df <- read.csv(csv_file_path, header = TRUE, na.strings = c(""," ", "NA"))
```