# Replace custom values with NA

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

```
df = data.frame("a" = c(1, 2, 3, "q", "r"),
                "b" = c(5,6,7,0,"s"))
dfWANT = data.frame("a" = c(1, 2, 3, "NA", "NA"),
                    "b" = c(5,6,7,0,"NA"))
REP = c("q", "r", "s")

df[,][df[,] == REP] <- NA
```

I aim to specify a list(`REP`) that has the scores I want to set to `NA`. Original data is `df` and the one I want is `dfWANT`. `REP` is the  vector of values I want to set to `NA` and the last line is my attempt that works only on col a.

Comment: This: `df = as.data.frame(lapply(df, as.numeric))`?

Comment: Or: `df = as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x%in%REP, NA,x)), stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: @R.Schifini Thanks so much but I do not wish to get rid of all characteristics/strings just the ones I specify in REP.

Comment: Not positive, but seems like this question should be mostly covered by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24172111/5325862)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sapply` to get a logical matrix of `TRUE`/`FALSE` value based on existence of `REP` value in it. We can then replace those `TRUE` values with `NA`.

```
df[sapply(df, `%in%`, REP)] <- NA

#     a    b
#1    1    5
#2    2    6
#3    3    7
#4 <NA>    0
#5 <NA> <NA>
```

In `dplyr`, we can use `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(~replace(., . %in% REP, NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the `data.frame` to `matrix` and do the `%in%` without looping in `base R`

```
df[`dim<-`(as.matrix(df) %in% REP, dim(df))] <- NA
df
#     a    b
#1    1    5
#2    2    6
#3    3    7
#4 <NA>    0
#5 <NA> <NA>
```

---

Or using the efficient `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
for(j in seq_along(df)) set(df, i = which(df[[j]] %in% REP),  j=j, value = NA_character_)
```