# Calculating a mean from a data frame with blanks with R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame with blanks at different positions. I would like to calculate a mean of the rows but I do not know how to make the n flexible depending on the row.

All the columns have the same amount of rows.

mean = sum/n

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(5, 9, NA, -0.9, -0.74, , 1.19, , -1, -0.4, 1.38, -1.5, 1, 0.64), 
                  col2 = c(4, 2, -9, 4, 19, 31, 4, -8, -15,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  col3 = c(1, -2, 5, 1.1, 33, 2, 7, 1, 1, 16, -22, - 2, -3,-10))
```

So that, for row1:

5+4+1 = 9/3 = 3

but for row 3:
(-9) + 5 = -4/2 = -2

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can just omit missing values: rowMeans(df1, na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: When I tried that, I get an error: "Error in rowMeans(df1, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be numeric." My values are numeric apart from the blanks, if that what it means.

Comment: Since you have those "blanks" (-0.74, ,1.19), you should convert them to NAs, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172111/change-the-blank-cells-to-na. If you read the dataframe from a file (e.g., a csv) you could do it online with the na.strings parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have blanks in your data that will turn your data to character even though it looks numeric. Turn them to `NA`, convert the column to numeric and then take mean.

```
df[df == ''] <- NA
df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
df$rowMean <- rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(col1 = as.numeric(c(5, 9, NA, -0.9, -0.74, NA , 1.19, 2 , -1, -0.4, 1.38, -1.5, 1, 0.64)), 
                  col2 = as.numeric(c(4, 2, -9, 4, 19, 31, 4, -8, -15,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)),
                  col3 = as.numeric(c(1, -2, 5, 1.1, 33, 2, 7, 1, 1, 16, -22, -2, -3,-10)))

 rowMeans(df1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

It is possible, that altough your data is numeric, R read them in as a character.

Comment: When I tried that, I got this error : Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' I tried to unlist it too using as.numeric(unlist(df1)). Both seem not to work.

Comment: `dft1 <- data.frame(col1 = as.numeric(c(5, 9, NA, -0.9, -0.74, NA , 1.19, 2 , -1, -0.4, 1.38, -1.5, 1, 0.64)), 
                  col2 = as.numeric(c(4, 2, -9, 4, 19, 31, 4, -8, -15,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)),
                  col3 = as.numeric(c(1, -2, 5, 1.1, 33, 2, 7, 1, 1, 16, -22, -2, -3,-10)))`

Comment: you can try this. and make every colum numeric. This should work, but is a bit of work

Comment: Seems like you create a data frame called `dftest` and then run rowmeans on something called `df1`.

Comment: my bad sorry. it should be df1