# How to take into account missing data in Kappa coefficient calculation?

Tags: r, kappa

I am calculating an inter-rater agreement for a biological question.
Basicaly, 6 readers are evaluated on 60 subjects with 2 possibilities categorical scale for each subjects.
I am using kappam.fleiss function on R to do so.

My question is: how to take into account missing data ?
If I put "NA" on my database, I am scared that NA would be interpreted as a new entry for the categorical interpretation. and thus would be associated with an abnormal kappa value.

Thanks a lot.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You could define during import, which cells should be recognized as NAs. See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172111/change-the-blank-cells-to-na). When you have NAs in the data, R is able to treat it as missing and not as valu. See more [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-missing-values/).