# R won't recognize missing data

Tags: r, data-manipulation, na, missing-data

I have a dataset with multiple columns. In some columns all values are missing, in other columns only a few values. When importing to R, the missing values are only shown as empty cells and not as NA.
This results in the problem that when I want to remove NA values with the `na.omit()` function nothing happens.
How should I handle this problem?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172111/change-the-blank-cells-to-na

Comment: How are you importing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace all the empty values with `NA` by using the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data_with_NA <- your_data %>% 
  mutate_all(na_if, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is often to fix this when importing your data. Most functions for importing data has some argument to specify which values should be interpreted as `NA`, for example:

- `read.csv` and the like: `na.strings`
- `readr::read_csv` and the like: `na`
- `readxl::read_excel` and the like: `na`

Just set this argument to `""`, `" "` or to any value that is not interpreted as `NA` by R.

If this is not an option for you, you can replace the blank values with NA using:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      everything(),
      ~na_if(.x, "")
    )
  )
```

> Note that `mutate(across(everything()))` has superseeded  `mutate_all` but [does the same](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html#how-do-you-convert-existing-code).

---

##### Data

```r
df <- mtcars %>% head()

df[1, 1] <- ""
```