# work around to specifying date range in ifelse statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, posixct

I am trying to create a new column denoting quarter in my `data.frame` using an `ifelse` statement on a date column of class `as.POSIXct` .

this is a short verion of the date

```
 a            

            spot.id local.date
q12014local.1  11824267 2013-12-30
q12014local.2  11825708 2013-12-30
q12014local.3  11823669 2013-12-30
q12014local.4  11825407 2013-12-30
q12014local.5  11824268 2013-12-30
q12014local.6  11825709 2013-12-30
q12014local.7  11823670 2013-12-30
q12014local.8  11825408 2013-12-30
q12014local.9  11824266 2013-12-31
q12014local.10 11825707 2013-12-31
```

This is the `ifelse` statement i wrote:
`> a$quarter <- ifelse(a$local.date >= 2013-07-01 & a$local.date <= 2013-09-30,"q32013",
ifelse(a$local.date >= 2013-10-01 & a$local.date <= 2013-12-31 , "q42013", 
ifelse(a$local.date >= 2014-01-01 & a$local.date <= 2014-03-31, "q12014", 
ifelse(a$local.date >= 2014-04-01 & a$local.date <= 2014-06-30, "q22014", ifelse(a$local.date >= 2014-07-01 & a$local.date <= 2014-09-30, "q32014", NA)))))`

For some reason, all I get is NA values in my new column ! I can use the row.names in my `data.frame` with a `gsub` like `a$quarter <- gsub("[\\.][0-9]+", "", row.names(a))` but that's not ideal. If `ifelse` is unclassing date objects, I tried using the function from this post : [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects) but that didn't work out. I still get NA values. What's the right way to achieve my objective ?

EDIT: Was unaware of the numerous functions like `quarters` , `format.yearqtr` available in `zoo` and `lubridate`. But related to the same, what if my quarters are not the same as calendar year quarters - For e.g. My quarter 1 begins in October, quarter 2 in Jan etc.

Comment: It may be better if you create some example data and the expected result so it becomes easier for others to test the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any extra package :

```
transform(dat,qu=paste0(quarters(local.date),format(local.date,'%Y')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(zoo)
a$quarter <- format.yearqtr(a$local.date, 'q%q%Y')
a
#                spot.id local.date quarter
#q12014local.1  11824267 2013-12-30  q42013
#q12014local.2  11825708 2013-12-30  q42013
#q12014local.3  11823669 2013-12-30  q42013
#q12014local.4  11825407 2013-12-30  q42013
#q12014local.5  11824268 2013-12-30  q42013
#q12014local.6  11825709 2013-12-30  q42013
#q12014local.7  11823670 2013-12-30  q42013
#q12014local.8  11825408 2013-12-30  q42013
#q12014local.9  11824266 2013-12-31  q42013
#q12014local.10 11825707 2013-12-31  q42013
```

#### Update

Based on the new info, about starting the `quarter` from `October`, may be this helps.

```
#creating the data
DATE <- seq(as.Date('1926-05-04'), length.out=1200, by='1 day')
month <- as.numeric(format(DATE,'%m'))
year <- as.numeric(format(DATE,'%Y'))
set.seed(25)
Val <- sample(0:120, 1200, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(DATE, month, year, Val, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$qtr <- ifelse(month %in% 10:12, 'q1', ifelse(month %in% 1:3,
                            'q2', ifelse(month %in% 4:6, 'q3', 'q4')))


indx <- df$year-min(df$year) + !df$month %in% 10:12
indx1 <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(indx) <0))
df$year2 <- indx1+ (min(df$year)-1)   
df$Quarter <- with(df, paste0(qtr,year2))
head(df)
```

#### Update2

Or based on @G. Grothendieck's comments

```
 format(as.yearqtr(df$DATE)-0.75, 'q%q%Y')
```

Comment: question : What if my quarters start from another year - meaning Q1 = Oct-Nov-Dec, Q2 = Jan-Feb-Mar etc.

Comment: @vagabond Please show it on your post and the expected result because others may not read all the comments.

Comment: `yearqtr` class stores its data as year plus 0 for Q1, .25 for Q2, .5 for Q3 and .75 for Q4 thus if `x` is a Date class variable then `as.yearqtr(x) - .75` gives the year/quarter with quarters starting in October.  For example, if `x <- as.Date("2014-11-08")` then it gives `2014 Q1`

Comment: @G. Grothendieck Thanks for the comments.  It is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `lubridate` package's `quarter()` function:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
            spot.id local.date
q12014local.1  11824267 2013-12-30
q12014local.2  11825708 2013-12-30
q12014local.3  11823669 2013-12-30
q12014local.4  11825407 2013-12-30
q12014local.5  11824268 2013-12-30
q12014local.6  11825709 2013-12-30
q12014local.7  11823670 2013-12-30
q12014local.8  11825408 2013-12-30
q12014local.9  11824266 2013-12-31
q12014local.10 11825707 2013-12-31", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$local.date <- as.POSIXct(df$local.date)

library('lubridate')
library('dplyr')

df %>%
  mutate(quarter = paste0("q", quarter(local.date), year(local.date)))
#     spot.id local.date quarter
# 1  11824267 2013-12-30  q42013
# 2  11825708 2013-12-30  q42013
# 3  11823669 2013-12-30  q42013
# 4  11825407 2013-12-30  q42013
# 5  11824268 2013-12-30  q42013
# 6  11825709 2013-12-30  q42013
# 7  11823670 2013-12-30  q42013
# 8  11825408 2013-12-30  q42013
# 9  11824266 2013-12-31  q42013
# 10 11825707 2013-12-31  q42013
```

Comment: question : What if my quarters start from another year - meaning Q1 = Oct-Nov-Dec, Q2 = Jan-Feb-Mar etc.