# Strange behavior involving dates - "origin must be supplied"

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a data.table like so

```
dt <- data.table(x=as.Date(c("2014-1-1", "2015-1-1", "2016-1-1")), y=as.Date(c(NA, "2015-6-1", NA)))
dt
            x          y
1: 2014-01-01       <NA>
2: 2015-01-01 2015-06-01
3: 2016-01-01       <NA>
```

I want to add a column `z` which is equal to y where y is not NA, and x otherwise.

```
dt[, z:=ifelse(is.na(y), x, y)]
dt
            x          y     z
1: 2014-01-01       <NA> 16071
2: 2015-01-01 2015-06-01 16587
3: 2016-01-01       <NA> 16801
```

But for some reason the above statement casts z to numeric.  If I try to convert it to a date with `as.Date` I get an error

```
dt[, z:=as.Date(ifelse(is.na(y), x, y))]
Error in as.Date.numeric(ifelse(is.na(y), x, y)) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

What gives and how do I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Regarding "for some reason [`ifelse`] casts z to numeric", see [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When R looks at dates as integers, its
>   origin is January 1, 1970.

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-date-values/

```
dt[, z:=as.Date(ifelse(is.na(y), x, y), origin="1970-01-01")]
```

*update:* as Frank suggests, this also seems to work and does not seem to require un-coercion:  `dt[, z:=replace(y, is.na(y), x)]`.  It throws a warning so use w/ caution.

Comment: instead of `ifelse`, `replace` is natural here. Also, with help files, you might want to provide the code to reach them `?dates`, rather than a link.

Comment: @Frank - thanks for the hint, although I did not find `?dates` terribly illuminating.  I am also not sure why `replace` throws `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` since `is.na(y)` and `x` are both length 3.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misread your url as a ethz one (which just mirrors built-in docs). The replace syntax is `replace(y,which(is.na(y)),x)` ... not sure if that resolves the error you're hitting.

Comment: Both variants using `replace()` return the wrong result. The warning must not be ignored. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51349025/3817004) for details.

Answer (score 8):

This old question has been viewed over ten thousand times now.

Although it has an accepted answer I feel the question deserves

- a genuine `data.table` solution,
- an explanation why `Date` fails with `ifelse()` and
- why the `replace()` approach returns the wrong results.

#### `data.table` approach

With `data.table`, `ifelse()` and `replace()` can be written as two chained assignment operations where the second one uses subsetting:

```
dt[, z := y][is.na(z), z := x][]
```

> ```
>             x          y          z
> 1: 2014-01-01       <NA> 2014-01-01
> 2: 2015-01-01 2015-06-01 2015-06-01
> 3: 2016-01-01       <NA> 2016-01-01
> ```

The first assignment operation creates a new column `z` by copying the `y` column. The second assignment operation modifies `z` *in place* by copying the contents of the `x` column *only to those rows* where `z` is `NA`.

Alternatively, we can take a copy of `x` first and the replace the `z` values with the non-`NA` `y` values:

```
dt <- copy(dt_orig)   # use a fresh copy of dt
dt[, z := x][!is.na(y), z := y][]
```

The latter might be more efficient if there are many `NA` values in `y`.

#### Errors in the `replace()` approaches

[Frank has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274536/strange-behavior-involving-dates-origin-must-be-supplied#comment50544621_31274734) to use `replace()` instead of `ifelse()` which was picked up by [C8H10N4O2 in an edit of his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31274734/3817004). Unfortunately, both codes not only generate warnings but simply *return the wrong result*:

```
dt <- copy(dt_orig)   # use a fresh copy of dt
# C8H10N4O2's version 
dt[, z := replace(y, is.na(y), x)][]

dt <- copy(dt_orig)   # use a fresh copy of dt
# Frank's version
dt[, z := replace(y, which(is.na(y)), x)][]
```

> ```
>             x          y          z
> 1: 2014-01-01       <NA> 2014-01-01
> 2: 2015-01-01 2015-06-01 2015-06-01
> 3: 2016-01-01       <NA> 2015-01-01
> Warning message:
> In NextMethod(.Generic) :
>   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> ```

The value of `z` in row 3 has been copied from `x` in row 2 which is wrong. Instead, it should have been copied from row 3.

What has happened here?  The help page on `replace(x, list, values)` says

> `replace` replaces the values in `x` with indices given in `list` by those given in `values`.

In our example, `list` gets the row indices `1, 3` while `values` gets `2014-01-01, 2015-01-01, 2016-01-01`. The different lengths is the reason for the warning message. And it is obvious that the second index in `list` which is row 3 is replaced by the second value in `values` which is `2015-01-01`.

*The correct use of `replace()` requires to subset `x` as well:*

```
dt <- copy(dt_orig)   # use a fresh copy of dt
dt[, z := replace(y, is.na(y), x[is.na(y)])][]
```

which yields

> ```
>             x          y          z
> 1: 2014-01-01       <NA> 2014-01-01
> 2: 2015-01-01 2015-06-01 2015-06-01
> 3: 2016-01-01       <NA> 2016-01-01
> ```

without any warning.

#### Why `Date` fails with `ifelse()`

The help page on `ifelse(test, yes, no)` has a long *Warning* section which starts

> The mode of the result may depend on the value of `test` [...], and the class attribute [...] of the result is
>   taken from `test` and may be inappropriate for the values selected from
>   `yes` and `no`.
>
> Sometimes it is better to use a construction such as
>
> ```
> (tmp <- yes; tmp[!test] <- no[!test]; tmp)
> ```

Applying this suggestion to our example

```
dt <- copy(dt_orig)   # use a fresh copy of dt
dt[, z := {tmp <- x; tmp[!is.na(y)] <- y[!is.na(y)]; tmp}][]
```

we do get

> ```
>             x          y          z
> 1: 2014-01-01       <NA> 2014-01-01
> 2: 2015-01-01 2015-06-01 2015-06-01
> 3: 2016-01-01       <NA> 2016-01-01
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.11.4 used
dt_orig <-data.table(x = as.Date(c("2014-1-1", "2015-1-1", "2016-1-1")), 
                y = as.Date(c(NA, "2015-6-1", NA)))
```

#### Benchmark

As there are 5 different approaches available now, I was wondering what the fastest method is. The run time may depend on the number of rows but also on the share of `NA` values in `y`.

So, the `press()` function from the `bench` package is used to investigate the impact of the two parameters on benchmarks results.

```
bm <- bench::press(
  n_rows = c(100, 1E4, 1E6),
  na_share = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9),
  {
    dt_bm <- data.table(x = as.Date("1970-01-01") + seq_len(n_rows),
                        y = as.Date("2970-01-01") + seq_len(n_rows))
    set.seed(1L)
    dt_bm[sample(seq_len(n_rows), na_share * n_rows), y := NA]
    bench::mark(
      ifelse = copy(dt_bm)[, z := as.Date(ifelse(is.na(y), x, y), origin="1970-01-01")][],
      replace = copy(dt_bm)[, z := replace(y, is.na(y), x[is.na(y)])][],
      tmp = copy(dt_bm)[, z := {tmp <- x; tmp[!is.na(y)] <- y[!is.na(y)]; tmp}][],
      copy_y = copy(dt_bm)[, z := y][is.na(z), z := x][],
      copy_x = copy(dt_bm)[, z := x][!is.na(y), z := y][]
    )
  }
)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(bm) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
dt[, z:=as.Date(ifelse(is.na(y), x, y),origin="1970-01-01")]
dt
            x          y          z
1: 2014-01-01       <NA> 2014-01-01
2: 2015-01-01 2015-06-01 2015-06-01
3: 2016-01-01       <NA> 2016-01-01
```