# Dates are not keeping specified format in R data frame

Tags: r, date, format, date-formatting, as.date

Simply put, I'm grabbing dates for events that meet certain conditions in df1 and putting them in a new data frame (df2).  The formatting of dates in df2 should be the same formatting in df1 ("2000-09-12", or %Y-%m-%d).  However, the dates in df2 read "11212", "11213", etc.

to generate data:

```
"Date"<-c("2000-09-08", "2000-09-11","2000-09-12","2000-09-13","2000-09-14","2000-09-15","2000-09-18","2000-09-19","2000-09-20","2000-09-21", "2000-09-22","2000-09-25")
"Event"<-c("A","N","O","O","O","O","N","N","N","N","N","A")
df1<-data.frame(Date,Event)
df1
         Date Event
1  2000-09-08     A
2  2000-09-11     N
3  2000-09-12     O
4  2000-09-13     O
5  2000-09-14     O
6  2000-09-15     O
7  2000-09-18     N
8  2000-09-19     N
9  2000-09-20     N
10 2000-09-21     N
11 2000-09-22     N
12 2000-09-25     A
```

here is the code:

```
"df2"<-data.frame()
"tmp"<-data.frame(1,2)
i<-c(1:4)
for (x in i)
  {
  date1<- df1$Date[df1$Event=="O"][x]
  date2<- df1$Date[df1$Event=="A" & df1$Date => date1] [1]
  as.numeric(difftime(date2, date1))->tmp[1,2]
  as.Date(as.character(df1$Date[df1$Event=="O"][x]), "%Y-%m-%d")->tmp[1,1] ##the culprit
  rbind(df2, tmp)->df2
}
```

Loop output looks like this:

```
     X1 X2
1 11212 13
2 11213 12
3 11214 11
4 11215 10
```

I want it to look like this:

```
            X1 X2
1 "2000-09-12" 13
2 "2000-09-13" 12
3 "2000-09-14" 11
4 "2000-09-14" 10
```

Comment: This is going to be difficult to help with unless you provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: will update question with some data

Comment: hmm, simply transforming the numeric input to date should work right? e.g., `as.Date(11212)`

Comment: @timfaber: that code produces "Error in as.Date.numeric(11212) : 'origin' must be supplied"

Comment: `as.Date(11212, origin="1970-01-01")` is what you wante. See the detail section in `?as.Date` for more info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274536/strange-behavior-involving-dates-origin-must-be-supplied

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to find for each `"O"` event the difference in days to the next following `"A"` event.

This can be solved using a *rolling join*. We extract the `"O"` events and the `"A"` events into two separate data.tables and join both on `date`.

This will avoid all the hassle with the data format and works also if `df1` is *not* already ordered by `Date`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Event == "A"][df1[Event == "O"], 
                         on = "Date", roll = -Inf, .(Date, x.Date - i.Date)]
```

> ```
>          Date      V2
> 1: 2000-09-12 13 days
> 2: 2000-09-13 12 days
> 3: 2000-09-14 11 days
> 4: 2000-09-15 10 days
> ```

Note that `roll = -Inf` rolls backwards (next observation carried backward (NOCB)) because the date of the next `"A"` event is required.

#### Data

```
Date <- as.Date(c("2000-09-08", "2000-09-11","2000-09-12","2000-09-13","2000-09-14","2000-09-15",
                  "2000-09-18","2000-09-19","2000-09-20","2000-09-21", "2000-09-22","2000-09-25"))
Event <- c("A","N","O","O","O","O","N","N","N","N","N","A")
df1 <- data.frame(Date,Event)
```