# R Markdown error in code when knit to HTML

Tags: r, markdown

I am trying to run code chunks in my markdown document. I have an R script that runs all the code that I need without any issues. Then, when I copy and paste the code into the markdown document, the code will run within the chunk, but will fail when trying to knit into an output document (html/pdf).

I had to create a safe.ifelse function to prevent r from converting my dates to a numeric format [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects).

The error appears to be with the code:

```
safe.ifelse = function(cond, yes, no){structure(ifelse(cond, yes, no), class = class(yes))
}
```

The error message I get is:

> Line 121 Error in structure(ifelse(cond,yes,no), class = class(yes)) : could not find function "days" Calls:  ... transform.data.frame ->eval->eval-> safe.ifelse-> structure Execution halted

The line of code following my safe.ifelse function is

```
seminoma1 = transform(seminoma1, recur.date = safe.ifelse(salvage.tx=="Yes",
date.diagnosis + days(pmax(time.rad, time.chemo, na.rm=TRUE)), NA))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is that the `days` function from the `lubridate` package? It looks from the error message (`could not find function "days"`) like you haven't loaded the package before calling the function.

Comment: without the transform, what does it do? I think your `safe.ifelse` function is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still too new to comment, but the only time I get an error like that is when I forget to define a function/variable or forget to source a package.

Since `days()` isn't part of R's base package, I think you need to add:

````
```{r echo = FALSE}
library("lubridate")
```
````

Comment: This solves the problem. I had the lubridate loaded, but I did not call it in the code chunk. Adding library("lubridate") to the beginning of the chunk fixed it.

Comment: `lubridate` was loaded only in your interactive session. R Studio opens a new, separate R session each time you compile an rmarkdown document, so you need to load any necessary packages within the rmarkdown document.