# ifelse and POSIXct: coercion and default class of NA

Tags: r, date, types, posix, na

Here is my example:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,4), col_2 = c('2017-12-1', '2015-11-2', '2011-2-5'))
my_df$col_2 <- as.POSIXct(my_df$col_2)
out <- ifelse(my_df$col_1 ==2, my_df$col_2+ as.difftime(3, units = 'days'), NA)
print(out)
```

It produces:

```
NA 1446703200         NA
```

So coercion happens because of different data type. What `NA` datatype should I use to prevent it: `NA_date_` or `NA_POSIX_` or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to do this stepwise with assignment instead of `ifelse`.

1) Create an index

```
i1 <- my_df$col_1 == 2
```

2) Assign values based on the index

```
my_df$col_2[i1] <- my_df$col_2[i1] + as.difftime(3, units = 'days')
```

3) Change other elements to NA

```
my_df$col_2[!i1] <- NA
my_df
#  col_1      col_2
#1     1       <NA>
#2     2 2015-11-05
#3     4       <NA>
```

---

The reason is that `POSIXct` storage mode is `numeric`, within `ifelse` it gets coerced to the `numeric` form

---

If we are using `tidyverse`, then

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df %>%
    mutate(col_2 =  col_2 + days(3), 
           col_2 = replace(col_2, col_1 != 2, NA))
```

Comment: The solution with index is much more universal and conceptual! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` makes it easy to modify specific rows

```
require(data.table)
my_df <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,4), col_2 = c('2017-12-1', '2015-11-2', '2011-2-5'))
setDT(my_df)
my_df[, col_2 := as.POSIXct(col_2)
      ][col_1 == 2, col_2 := col_2 + as.difftime(3, units = 'days')
      ][col_1 != 2, col_2 := NA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you (for some reason ;)) have loaded `dplyr`, you may use `if_else` and wrap the `false` `NA` in `as.POSIXct`*:

```
if_else(my_df$col_1 == 2, my_df$col_2 + as.difftime(3, units = 'days'), as.POSIXct(NA))
# [1] NA               "2015-11-05 CET" NA
```

---

*See `?as.POSIXct`:

> Logical `NA`s can be converted to either of the classes [`POSIXlt` and `POSIXct`]

---

Related question:

[How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects). See also [the comment by @roarkz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects#comment76543672_38093096) and my answer.

Comment: Lol, I loaded `dplyr` with intention to use `if_else` and simply forgot correct spelling of it.