# If date is on Sunday, then change date to the following Monday

Tags: r, date

Sunday date in mydates is 2018-05-06.  I would like 1 day added so that 2018-05-06 becomes 2018-05-07 (Monday).  That is, if a date falls on a Sunday add one day.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydates <- as.Date(c('2018-05-01','2018-05-02','2018-05-05','2018-05-06'))

# find which are weekend dates
x = as.character(wday(mydates,TRUE))

if(x == 'Sun') { mydates + 1 }                  

# the Sunday date in mydates is 2018-05-06.  I would like 1 day added so 
that 2018-05-06 becomes 2018-05-07
```

Here's my error:  Warning message:
In if (x == "Sun") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: x and mydates are vectors... no reason to use x == "Sun" or mydates + 1... you can use for loop..

Answer (score 1):

Try `ifelse`. Then convert to class `Date`.

```
as.Date(ifelse(x == 'Sun', mydates + 1, mydates), origin = '1970-01-01')
#[1] "2018-05-01" "2018-05-02" "2018-05-05" "2018-05-07"
```

Answer (score 0):

X is a vector so you can use an`if_else` statement to increment the Sundays as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
new_dates <- if_else(x == 'Sun', mydates + days(1), mydates)
```

Comment: `if_else` is from `dplyr`...you should mention that...anyways `ifelse` should also be fine here...

Comment: @Shree Not really. See [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects)

Comment: Shree, the dplyr package was imported in the question but I updated my answer to make it complete

Comment: @Henrik...interesting! I wasn't aware of that `ifelse` behavior.

Comment: @GordonShumway...makes sense...I hadn't noticed `dplyr` in the question I guess...

Answer (score 0):

First, identify which of your dates are Sundays. Then, selectively add 1

```
library(lubridate)
mydates <- as.Date(c('2018-05-01','2018-05-02','2018-05-05','2018-05-06'))

i <- which(as.character(wday(mydates,TRUE))=="Sun")
mydates[i] <- mydates[i]+1
```

this outputs

```
 "2018-05-01" "2018-05-02" "2018-05-05" "2018-05-07"
```

which, I believe, is the desired result.