# Conditionally update date in a dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following data.

```
 df_a <- data.frame(id=c("John","Ben","Bill", "Eminem"),
                     amount=c("300", "500", "1000", "1200"),
                     issue_date=as.Date(c("2010-01-01","2011-01-01","2012-01-01", "2015-02-01")),
                     last_pymnt_date=as.Date(c("2013-02-01","2012-05-01","2014-01-01", "2018-02-01")),
                     months_passed=c(37,16,24,36),
                     term = c("36", "36", "36", "36"),
                     status=c("Fully Paid",
                              "Charged off",
                              "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Charged Off",
                              "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Fully Paid"),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

    library(DescTools)
    df_a$maturity_dt <- AddMonths(df_a$issue_date, 36)
```

I want to make the `last_pymnt_date` same as `maturity_dt` if `status` variable includes the expression "Fully Paid". If I run the following line it makes `last_pymnt_date` variable some numbers.

```
df_a$last_pymnt_date <- ifelse(grepl("Fully Paid", df_a$status),
                               df_a$maturity_dt,
                               df_a$last_pymnt_date)
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `ifelse` does not handle dates well. See [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do this. Just separated out `grepl` test to improve readability.

```
test <- grepl("Fully Paid", df_a$status)

df_a$last_pymnt_date[test] <- df_a$maturity_dt[test]
```

Comment: df_a$maturity_dt <- AddMonths(df_a$issue_date, 36) im constructing it by this line

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Anyways, the above code should work for you. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. Whats the problem with ifelse code that i was doing? i guess the logic is OK

Comment: Replied in comments to your post so that everyone will see it.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `dplyr`:

```
df_a$last_pymnt_date <- dplyr::if_else(grepl("Fully Paid", df_a$status),
                                       df_a$maturity_dt, 
                                       df_a$last_pymnt_date)
```

`dplyr`'s `case_when` is also a good alternative to `ifelse`, especially if you have more conditions:

```
df_a$last_pymnt_date <- dplyr::case_when(
                                   grepl("Fully Paid", df_a$status) ~ df_a$maturity_dt, 
                                   TRUE ~ df_a$last_pymnt_date)
```

Or using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

df_a <- setDT(df_a)[grepl("Fully Paid", status), last_pymnt_date := maturity_dt]
```