# Replace future dates with NA using dplyr

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, lubridate, tibble

I have a `tibble` with several columns containing dates, some of which are in the future (e.g., 2019-08-26). I need to replace the dates that are in the future with `NA`, and want to do so using `dplyr`.

So far I have the following, which does not work:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
d <- tibble("ID" = 1:9,
            "Date1" = as_date(c("2019-08-05", "2019-08-26", "2019-08-26",
                                "2019-08-26", "2019-07-29", "2019-08-12", 
                                "2019-08-19", "2019-08-26", "2019-08-26")),
            "Date2" = as_date(c("2019-08-12", "2019-09-02", "2019-09-02",
                                 "2019-09-02", "2019-08-05", "2019-08-19",
                                 "2019-08-26", "2019-09-02", "2019-09-02")))

d %>%
  select("Date1") %>%
  replace(. > today(), NA) #This line doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help(replace)`

> **Arguments**
>
> x:    vector

So use `pull` instead

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  pull("Date1") %>%
  replace(. > today(), NA)
#[1] "2019-08-05" NA           NA           NA           "2019-07-29"
#[6] "2019-08-12" "2019-08-19" NA           NA
```

If you need a `tibble` and try to replace those values, use `mutate`

```
d %>%
 mutate(Date2 = replace(Date1, Date1 > Sys.Date(), NA))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#     ID Date1      Date2     
#  <int> <date>     <date>    
#1     1 2019-08-05 2019-08-05
#2     2 2019-08-26 NA        
#3     3 2019-08-26 NA        
#4     4 2019-08-26 NA        
#5     5 2019-07-29 2019-07-29
#6     6 2019-08-12 2019-08-12
#7     7 2019-08-19 2019-08-19
#8     8 2019-08-26 NA        
#9     9 2019-08-26 NA
```

---

As pointed out by @d.b. in the comments and also in [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects) `if_else` and `ifelse`, and dates don't go along together very well.

```
# don't run
# d %>% mutate(Date2 = ifelse(Date1 < today(), Date1, NA))
```

**update**

If you have multiple columns an option is `mutate_if`

```
d %>%
  mutate_if(., is.Date, .funs = ~replace(., . > today(), NA))
```

Comment: Making `d %>% mutate(Date2 = ifelse(Date1 < today(), Date1, NA))` work is quite a hassle

Comment: This works great! It is possible to do this to multiple columns at once using something like `mutate_at`?

Comment: markus and @d.b. thank you both. Very new to dplyr so still learning how it works. Appreciate it!