# Assign a name to a cell while there is a value in another cell in R

Tags: r

There is a df with two columns as follows:

| method | Value |
| --- | --- |
| H2O | 10.2 |
| NA | 5.4 |
| NA | NA |

I want to assign the word "H2O" to the method column instead of `NA` if there is a corresponding value (here is 5.4, but any value) in the Value column. So I want the df to look like this:

| method | Value |
| --- | --- |
| H2O | 10.2 |
| H2O | 5.4 |
| NA | NA |

I am looking for a piece of code in R to do this for my entire table.

Answer (score 1):

1. Indexed assignment:

   ```r
   df$method[is.na(df$method) & !is.na(df$Value)] <- "H2O"
   df
   #   method Value
   # 1    H2O  10.2
   # 2    H2O   5.4
   # 3   <NA>    NA
   ```
2. `ifelse`:

   ```r
   ifelse(is.na(df$method) & !is.na(df$Value), "H2O", df$method)
   ```
3. `replace` (can be safer than `ifelse`)

   ```r
   replace(df$method, is.na(df$method) & !is.na(df$Value), "H2O")
   ```

(2 and 3 need to be assigned back to the column, of course.)

Comment: Thanks r2evans, That is a great help.

Comment: @r2evans , why is replace safer tham ifelse?

Comment: For one, compare `replace(rep(Sys.time(), 2), c(T,F), Sys.time())` with `ifelse(c(T,F), Sys.time(), Sys.time())`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272