# Assignment in an if statment over data frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, assign

I hope someone could take a look at the if statement below and tell my how I should change it to get the results I want.

Essentially, I want the code to (1) run through (iterate over) every row in the data frame beh_data, and (2) if the character in the "Cue" column is identical to that in the "face1" column, I want to (3) take the value from the "Enc_trials.thisRepN" column, and (4) assign it to the "scr_of_trial" column. If they are not the same, I want to assign an NA to the "scr_of_trial" column.

Currently, the code runs, but assings NA to every row in the "scr_of_trial" column.

Can anyone tell me why?

**Here is the code:**

```
j <- 1
i = as.character(beh_data$Cue[1:1])

for (x in 1:NROW(beh_data$Cue)) {
  if (beh_data$Cue[j] == beh_data$face1[j]) {
    beh_data$scr_of_trial[j] <- beh_data$Enc_trials.thisRepN[j]

j <- j + 1
i = as.character(beh_data$Cue[1:1+j])
}

else {
  beh_data$scr_of_trial[j] <- NA

  j <- j + 1
  i = as.character(beh_data$Cue[1:1+j])
  
  next

 }
}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal representation of your data including an output example. Otherwise its impossible to give you solid advice other than maybes.

Answer (score 0):

Shift your thinking to whole-vectors-at-a-time.

A few techniques:

1. `ifelse`; while it works fine here, realize that `ifelse` has [issues with `class`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272).

   ```r
   beh_data$scr_of_trial <- ifelse(beh_data$Cue == beh_data$face1,
                                   beh_data$Enc_trials.thisRepN, NA_character_)
   ```
2. `replace`; similar functionality, no `class` problem:

   ```r
   replace(beh_data$Enc_trials.thisRepN, beh_data$Cue != beh_data$face1, NA_character_)
   ```
3. Use what I call an "indicator variable":

   ```r
   ind <- beh_data$Cue == beh_data$face1
   beh_data$scr_of_trial <- NA_character_
   beh_data$scr_of_trial[ind] <- beh_data$Enc_trials.thisRepN
   ```

No `for` loops, just whole vectors at a time.

When reasonable, I tend to use class-specific `NA` types like `NA_character_`; while base R's functions will happily up-convert for you to whatever class you have, many other dialects within R (e.g., `dplyr`, `data.table`) are less permissive. It's a little declarative programming, a little style, perhaps a little snobbery, I don't know ...

(This is all untested on actual data.)