# Trying to assign a number to a variable value R

Tags: r, vector, categorical-data

I am trying to loop through the values within a categorical variable and assign a number based on whether the value is "yes" or "no"

My data is "train" and the variable is "default" which looks as follow:

```
default = c("no", "yes", "no"....)
```

I want to create a separate vector which contains thee number 10 for any value of "yes" and the number 1 for nay value "no."

I tried:

```
wgts = c()
for (y in 1:nrow(train)) {
  ifelse(train$default[y] == "yes", wgts = append(wgts[y], 10), wgts = append(wgts[y], 1))
  return(wgts)
}
```

But the resulting vector is turning out to be NULL. How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `ifelse` when doing single comparisons, use `if` (and `else`). (1) Don't do assignment within it. (2) Declarative programming, if you intend a single, use `if`. (3) `if` is primitive, much faster. (4) `ifelse` has baggage: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a for loop here, just use:

```
ifelse(default == "yes", 10,1)
```

This assumes you only have yes or no in your vector.
A short sample:

```
default <- c("yes","no")

ifelse(default == "yes", 10,1)
```

If you need some more speed, you can simply subset the vector:

```
default[default=="yes"] <- 10
default[default=="no"]<-1
default <- as.numeric(default)
```

This way you overwrite your default vector.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(default == 'yes' ~ 10, TRUE ~ 1)
```