# How can I add a new column and use an existing column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column called "Visited" which looks at an existing column called "Visits" and if "visits" = NA, then i want "visited" to = 0, but if "visits" > 0, "visited" should = 1. I am getting an error which states "Error in mutate(Visited = if (Visits == "NA") { :
object 'Visits' not found". Thank you for all advice!! Here is my code.

`````
mutate(Visited = 
  if(Visits == "NA") {
  replace("NA", 0)
  } else {
  replace(1)
  }
)````
`````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` should do the trick. Note: `df` can be replaced by your `dataframe`s name:

```
df$Visited = ifelse(is.na(df$Visits), 0, 1)
```

If you prefer `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>%
        mutate(Visited = ifelse(is.na(Visits), 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Some issues:

1. You cannot use `if` in a `mutate` like this: I'm inferring that your data is more than one row, in which case `Visits == "NA"` will be a `logical` *vector*, length greater than 1. The `if` conditional **must** have length-1. What you likely need is a vectorized conditional such as `ifelse` or `replace`.

   There are a few things to realize: vectorized conditionals do not short-circuit (`&&` and `||` *do* short-circuit, `&` and `|` do not, and you cannot just interchange them); and [`ifelse` has issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272) with classes other than `logical`, `integer`, `numeric`, and `character`.
2. Your use of `replace` is incorrect: it requires three arguments, it infers nothing. You cannot use just `replace(0)` hoping that it will know to look for a conditional outside of its call.
3. There is a big difference between the R symbol `NA` (which can be `numeric`, `logical`, string, etc) and the string `"NA"`. There are times when mis-read data gives you strings of `"NA"`, but typically it's not. Note that `NA == .` anything is going to be `NA` (not true/false), since `NA` can be interpreted as *"can be anything"* as well as "not applicable". Because of this, if you have `NA`s in your code, then `. == "NA"` is going to first internally coerce the data to strings, which does not convert `NA` to `"NA"`, and then look for the literal `"NA"`, not what you want/need. I hope that makes sense.
4. The error message suggests that you are not passing in *data*. `mutate(Visited = ...)` works fine if the call to mutate is in a dplyr/magrittr "pipe" (`%>%`), but by itself `mutate` requires its first argument to be a `data.frame`, as in `mutate(mydata, Visited=...)`.

Here are some equivalent alternatives that should work for you:

```r
mydata %>%
  mutate(
    Visited1 = ifelse(!is.na(Visits) & Visits > 0, 1, 0),
    Visited2 = replace(rep(1, n()), is.na(Visits) | Visits <= 0, 0),
    Visited3 = +(!is.na(Visits) & Visits > 0)
  )
```

The third takes advantage of R's coercion from `logical` to `integer` with the `+(.)` shortcut.

You pick which you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation! I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Visited = if_else(is.na(Visits), 0, 1))
  Visits Visited
1     NA       0
2      2       1
3      1       1
4     NA       0
5      5       1
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Visits = c(NA, 2, 1, NA, 5)
)
```