# Preserving column types when applying ifelse() across columns of different types in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, across

This seems to be a fairly simple task, but I couldn't figure it out after studying the documentation of `ifelse()`, `dplyr::if_else()` and several similar posts on SO about applying `ifelse()` to multiple columns in a data frame.

**My goal:** I have the following data frame with columns of different data types. On each row, I want to reset the values in the first 3 columns to NA, if Column "valid" indicates false.

**The problem:** I used `dplyr::across()` and `ifelse()` to change the values as I wanted, but the date Column `date` and factor Column `team` were coerced to numeric (as shown in the reprex below), which wasn't desirable. I know that `dplyr::if_else()` preserves data types, but it doesn't work across columns of different data types, either.

I know `tdf[tdf$valid == FALSE, !grepl("valid", names(tdf))] <- NA` could achieve my goal, but I prefer a tidyverse approach, which I could use in my data cleaning pipeline. Many thanks in advance!

```r
library(dplyr)

tdf <- tibble(
  date = c(as.Date("2021-12-10"), as.Date("2021-12-11")),
  team = factor(1:2, labels = c("T1", "T2")),
  score = 3:4,
  valid = c(TRUE, FALSE)
)

tdf
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   date       team  score valid
#>   <date>     <fct> <int> <lgl>
#> 1 2021-12-10 T1        3 TRUE 
#> 2 2021-12-11 T2        4 FALSE

tdf %>% mutate(across(-valid, ~ ifelse(valid, ., NA)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>    date  team score valid
#>   <dbl> <int> <int> <lgl>
#> 1 18971     1     3 TRUE 
#> 2    NA    NA    NA FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the default (`TRUE`) option in `case_when` which returns the `NA` based on the type

```
library(dplyr)
tdf %>%
    mutate(across(-valid, ~ case_when(valid ~ .)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  date       team  score valid
  <date>     <fct> <int> <lgl>
1 2021-12-10 T1        3 TRUE 
2 NA         <NA>     NA FALSE
```

---

Or another option is `replace`

```
tdf %>% 
   mutate(across(-valid, ~ replace(., !valid, NA)))
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  date       team  score valid
  <date>     <fct> <int> <lgl>
1 2021-12-10 T1        3 TRUE 
2 NA         <NA>     NA FALSE
```

---

According to `?ifelse`

> The mode of the result may depend on the value of test (see the examples), and the class attribute (see oldClass) of the result is taken from test and may be inappropriate for the values selected from yes and no.

> Sometimes it is better to use a construction such as

> (tmp <- yes; tmp[!test] <- no[!test]; tmp)

> , possibly extended to handle missing values in test.

Comment: What a comprehensive answer! Thanks so much, @akrun! Both solutions with `case_when` and `replace` work well and are very neat! I need to study more about the tools I used on a daily basis... 

Answer (score 2):

This is a not solved issue:

@akrun gives a very good explanation and how you could solve your specific problem!

But in case if you want to keep `ifelse`:

The only working solution **(with dates and factors)** in your specific case is provided by Fabian Werner in 2015 using a custom **`safe.ifelse`**

[How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects)

```
safe.ifelse <- function(cond, yes, no) {
  class.y <- class(yes)
  if (class.y == "factor") {
    levels.y = levels(yes)
  }
  X <- ifelse(cond,yes,no)
  if (class.y == "factor") {
    X = as.factor(X)
    levels(X) = levels.y
  } else {
    class(X) <- class.y
  }
  return(X)
}

tdf %>% mutate(across(-valid, ~ safe.ifelse(valid, ., NA)))
```

```
  date       team  score valid
  <date>     <fct> <int> <lgl>
1 2021-12-10 T1        3 TRUE 
2 NA         NA       NA FALSE
```

Comment: Argh, I missed that post! Thanks very much, @TarJae, for kindly sharing the solution here. It's definitely useful to learn how to solve it without relying on other packages!