# How to replace Inf with NA and keep date?

Tags: r

How can I keep the column as a date when replacing `Inf` values with NA?

```
df <- data.frame(a = structure(c(18628, Inf), class = "Date"))
df$a <- ifelse(is.infinite(df$a), NA, df$a)
df$a
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects)

Comment: @caldwellst actually no, because when I tried replacing my ifelse with if_else or fifelse says they are not the same type

Comment: You can use `replace()` - `replace(df$a, is.infinite(df$a), NA)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it into `structure` like you did providing your data. This is similar (but not identical) what *@hadley* reccomends in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects#).

```
structure(ifelse(is.infinite(df$a), NA, df$a), class="Date")
# [1] "2021-01-01" NA
```

Or less hardcoded:

```
structure(ifelse(is.infinite(df$a), NA, df$a), class=class(df$a))
# [1] "2021-01-01" NA
```

`"Date"` and similar classes are sometimes awkward because they are converted to numeric values; remember that and get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple indexing operation works.

```
df <- data.frame(a = structure(c(18628, Inf), class = "Date"))
df$a[is.infinite(df$a)] <- NA # or df[is.infinite(df$a), 'a'] <- NA
```

```
> df
           a
1 2021-01-01
2       <NA>

> class(df$a)
[1] "Date"
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just wrap `NA` in `as.Date`?

```
data.table::fifelse(is.infinite(df$a), as.Date(NA), df$a)
```

OR

```
dplyr::if_else(is.infinite(df$a),as.Date(NA), df$a)
```