# Mutate with ifelse multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, mutated

I have dataframe like below

```
monkey = data.frame(girl = 1:10, kn = NA, boy = 5)
```

And i want to understand the following code meaning step by step

```
monkey %>%
  mutate(t = ifelse(is.na(kn),.[,grepl('a',names(.))],ll))
```

Thank you everyone in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is not good code, but I'll try to explain what it is doing.

- `is.na(kn)` (in the context of `monkey`) returns a logical vector of whether each value in that column is `NA`,

  ```r
  with(monkey, is.na(kn))
  #  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
  ```
- The use of `.` in `.[grepl(*)]` refers to the current data at the start of this call to `mutate`; it would be more dplyr-canonical to use `cur_data()`, which would be more-complete (e.g., taking into account previous mutated columns that `.` does not recognize, not a factor here). I believe this `.[*]` code is trying to select a column dynamically based on the current data.

  **Why this one is bad:**
  1. There is no column *here* whose name contains `"a"`;
  2. There could be more than one columns whose names contain `"a"`, which means the `yes=` argument to `ifelse` would produce a nested frame in the new `t=` column;
  3. The behavior of `.[,*]` changes if the original frame is the base-R `data.frame` or if it is the tibble-variant `tbl_df`: see `monkey[,1]` versus `tibble(monkey)[,1]`.
- `no=` argument refers to an object `ll` that is not defined. This *should* (intuitively) fail with `Error: object 'll' not found` or similar, but since all of the `test=` argument is true, the `no=` is not needed and so it not evaluated. Consider `ifelse(c(TRUE, TRUE), 1:2, stop("oops"))` (no error) versus `ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1:2, stop("oops"))`.

Ultimately, this code is not defensive-enough to be safe (base-vs-tibble variant) and its intent is unclear.

My advice when using `dplyr` is to use `dplyr::if_else` instead of base R's `ifelse`. For one, `ifelse` has some issues and limitations (e.g., [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272)); for another, `if_else` protects you from ambiguous, inconsistent-results code such as in your question.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I did not know about this accepting feature, I will pay attention @r2evans

Comment: Thank you very much for going back to your previous questions, too!