# Changing date fields in an R data frame on next values?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am having a problem in my data set due to a data issue which is coming from the application, usually the dataset will have one unique row with a start time and an end time. Each row in the dataset corresponds to a an ID which always have 11 'checks' with a corresponding start time and an end time. But due to an issue we got two start times and end time which ruined the data set.

What I am envisioning to do is basically using dplyr and use the mutate function to check if the end time for a check for an ID is greater than the start time of the next check (ideally this should never happen but this happened so I want my code to check for these nuances and fix it).

The fix what I am looking for is that the end time for a specific check of an ID to be always smaller than the start time for the next check).

```
# My data looks like this:
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A),
                 "Check"= c(1:11),
                 "Start_time" = c("2022-09-01 00:00:00.0","2022-09-01 00:00:00.0","2022-09-01 00:00:00.0","2022-09-14 13:03:00.0","2022-09-14 13:04:32.531","2022-09-14 13:04:35.0","2022-09-14 17:04:32.965","2022-09-19 22:05:10.137","2022-09-20 22:09:39.456","2022-09-22 18:44:06.992",
    "2022-09-22 19:40:31.852","2022-09-22 15:41:02.0"),
                 "end_time" = c("2022-09-01 00:00:00.0","2022-09-01 00:00:00.0","2022-09-19 18:03:44.0","2022-09-19 18:05:08.0","2022-09-19 18:05:01.694","2022-09-19 18:05:06.0","2022-09-19 22:05:10.137","2022-09-20 22:09:39.456","2022-09-21 12:40:24.32","2022-09-22 18:44:06.992",
    "2022-09-22 19:40:31.852","2022-09-23 12:05:07.0")
                 )
```

What I am trying myself to do this:

```
df %>%
group_by(ID,Check) %>% 
mutate(end_time = ifelse(end_time>Start_time,Start_time,end_time)
```

But this approach with DPLYR is not clearly working and I don't see the end times being updated, maybe it has do with each ID having checks 1-5 so R doesn't know maybe for which check it should do this.

solution#2 which seems to be working but I don't think its an efficient way to do it:

```
df$end_time[df$check==1] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==1] > df$start_time[df$check==2],df$start_time[df$check==2],df$end_time[df$check==1]))
df$end_time[df$check==2] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==2]>df$start_time[df$check==3],df$start_time[df$check==3],df$end_time[df$check==2]))
df$end_time[df$check==3] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==3]>df$start_time[df$check==4],df$start_time[df$check==4],df$end_time[df$check==3]))
df$end_time[df$check==4] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==4]>df$start_time[df$check==5],df$start_time[df$check==5],df$end_time[df$check==4]))
df$end_time[df$check==5] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==5]>df$start_time[df$check==6],df$start_time[df$check==6],df$end_time[df$check==5]))
df$end_time[df$check==6] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==6]>df$start_time[df$check==7],df$start_time[df$check==7],df$end_time[df$check==6]))
df$end_time[df$check==7] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==7]>df$start_time[df$check==8],df$start_time[df$check==8],df$end_time[df$check==7]))
df$end_time[df$check==8] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==8]>df$start_time[df$check==9],df$start_time[df$check==9],df$end_time[df$check==8]))
df$end_time[df$check==9] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==9]>df$start_time[df$check==10],df$start_time[df$check==10],df$end_time[df$check==9]))
df$end_time[df$check==10] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==10]>df$start_time[df$check==11],df$start_time[df$check==11],df$end_time[df$check==10]))
df$end_time[df$check==11] <- as_datetime(ifelse(df$end_time[df$check==11]>df$start_time[df$check==12],df$start_time[df$check==12],df$end_time[df$check==11]))
```

Comment: Of course this is not true data, this is just something which i made up. I have actual start and end dates.

Comment: @samR the 'end_time' and 'start_time' fields are 'POSIXct' data type aka datetime.

Comment: okay let me edit and get back

Comment: @samR i added real time stamps and removed ID B since i think it would have made the example a little bit complicated for users.

But ID field can have more than 1 ID's each having 11 checks with 11 start time and end times.

Answer (score 0):

In the data you have posted, the `Start_time` and `end_time` columns are `character` vectors. So I had to `mutate()` them. You can skip that if your they are `POSIXct` in your data.

The second issue is that `ifelse()` can [never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects) return an object of class `POSIXct`. But you can use `dplyr::if_else` (or `data.table::fifelse()`) which can:

```r
df |>
    mutate(
        across(Start_time:end_time, as.POSIXct)
    ) |>
    group_by(ID,Check) |> 
    mutate(
        end_time = if_else(
            end_time>Start_time,
            Start_time,
            end_time
        )
    )

# # A tibble: 12 x 4
# # Groups:   ID, Check [12]
#    ID    Check Start_time          end_time
#    <chr> <int> <dttm>              <dttm>
#  1 A         1 2022-09-01 00:00:00 2022-09-01 00:00:00
#  2 A         2 2022-09-01 00:00:00 2022-09-01 00:00:00
#  3 A         3 2022-09-01 00:00:00 2022-09-01 00:00:00
#  4 A         4 2022-09-14 13:03:00 2022-09-14 13:03:00
#  5 A         5 2022-09-14 13:04:32 2022-09-14 13:04:32
#  6 A         6 2022-09-14 13:04:35 2022-09-14 13:04:35
#  7 A         7 2022-09-14 17:04:32 2022-09-14 17:04:32
#  8 A         8 2022-09-19 22:05:10 2022-09-19 22:05:10
#  9 A         9 2022-09-20 22:09:39 2022-09-20 22:09:39
# 10 A        10 2022-09-22 18:44:06 2022-09-22 18:44:06
# 11 A        11 2022-09-22 19:40:31 2022-09-22 19:40:31
# 12 A        12 2022-09-22 15:41:02 2022-09-22 15:41:02
```

#### Input data:

```r
df  <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
"A", "A", "A", "A"), Check = 1:12, Start_time = c("2022-09-01 00:00:00.0",
"2022-09-01 00:00:00.0", "2022-09-01 00:00:00.0", "2022-09-14 13:03:00.0",
"2022-09-14 13:04:32.531", "2022-09-14 13:04:35.0", "2022-09-14 17:04:32.965",
"2022-09-19 22:05:10.137", "2022-09-20 22:09:39.456", "2022-09-22 18:44:06.992",
"2022-09-22 19:40:31.852", "2022-09-22 15:41:02.0"), end_time = c("2022-09-01 00:00:00.0",
"2022-09-01 00:00:00.0", "2022-09-19 18:03:44.0", "2022-09-19 18:05:08.0",
"2022-09-19 18:05:01.694", "2022-09-19 18:05:06.0", "2022-09-19 22:05:10.137",
"2022-09-20 22:09:39.456", "2022-09-21 12:40:24.32", "2022-09-22 18:44:06.992",
"2022-09-22 19:40:31.852", "2022-09-23 12:05:07.0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-12L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i am trying both the as_datetime before ifelse and also dplyr::ifelse but still the data is not successfully being changed