# making a new column in R dataframe based on a selection of values from other columns

Tags: r, select, dplyr, data.table, apply

I have a dataframe as below:

```
data <- data.table (x= c(1,2,3,4,5), y= c(7,6,8,9,10), z= c('a','b','c','d','e'), w=c(01.05, 03.04, 11.08, 05.07, 09.18))
```

I need to make a new column containing values as I describe below:
whenever x equals 3 or 5, or y equals 7, then make a new column called M and insert the value in the corresponding row from w into column M, and leave the other rows empty.
The data shuld then look like this:

```
data <- data.table (x= c(1,2,3,4,5), y= c(7, 6,8,9,10), z= c('a','b','c','d','e'), w=c(01.05, 03.04, 11.08, 05.07, 09,18), M=c(01.05, NA, 11.08, NA, 09.18)
```

I am a beginner in R and searched a lot but could not find a solution. I tried using case_when and apply functions but no luck. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: try `data %>% mutate(m = ifelse(x %in% c(3,5)|y==7,w,NA_real_))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `data.table`, this is the way to assign `:=` a new variable. You can use `ifelse` or even better `fifelse` (to ensure `M` will be the same class as `w`) to check for your conditions, using `%in%` and `|`.

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table (x = c(1:5), y = c(7,6,8,9,10), z = letters[1:5], 
                    w = c(01.05, 03.04, 11.08, 05.07, 09.18))

data[, M := fifelse(x %in% c(3,5) | y == 7, w, NA_real_)]
data
#>    x  y z     w     M
#> 1: 1  7 a  1.05  1.05
#> 2: 2  6 b  3.04    NA
#> 3: 3  8 c 11.08 11.08
#> 4: 4  9 d  5.07    NA
#> 5: 5 10 e  9.18  9.18
```

**Edit**: r2evans' approach in the comment below this answer does the same but is more elegant:

`data[x %in% c(3,5) | y == 7, M := w]`

Comment: If you're already loading `data.table`, I strongly recommend the habit pattern of using `fifelse`. Not only does it guard against some mistakes like inadvertently converting from numbers to strings, it is not prone to [`ifelse` stripping classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272).

Comment: An alternative to using ifelse logic at all could be: `data[x %in% c(3,5) | y == 7, M := w]` (assuming that `M` does not previously exist ... which it doesn't here)

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY I like your alternative and think it's better! Will you include it as an answer or shall I include that option in mine crediting you?

Comment: Please add it to yours, it's not cosmically different enough to warrant another answer. (With or without credit, I'm good. Thanks!)

Comment: @VvdL Thank you both for your detailed reply. I just learned that I had confused data.table with dataframe. My data was indeed a dataframe and therefore, Eric's answer worked. Your reply taught me something new.

Comment: @VvdL I need your help with something else here. Could you please tell me how I can exclude missing values in this line? data[, M := fifelse(x %in% c(3,5) | y == 7, w, NA_real_)]

Comment: @Eric I need your help with something else here. Could you please tell me how I can exclude missing values in this line? data %>% mutate(m = ifelse(x %in% c(3,5)|y==7,w,NA_real_))