# Replace a specific NA value with a character in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am looking for a clever way to replace a specific NA value with a character.

An example data.frame would look like this

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(genes=c("A","B","C"), x=c(NA,NA,4), y=c(NA,3,4))
df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   genes     x     y
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A        NA    NA
#> 2 B        NA     3
#> 3 C         4     4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I want to replace when `gene==A` the `NA value` in the x column with `Yes`. The rest of the values in the x column should remain the same. I tried with `mutate` and `case_when()`, but I am taking an error.

I want my date to look  like this

```
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>    genes     x     y
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   A       Yes    NA
#> 2   B        NA     3
#> 3   C         4     4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `ifelse` with `is.na` and condition on genes like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(x) & genes == 'A', 'Yes', x))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   genes x         y
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A     Yes      NA
#> 2 B     <NA>      3
#> 3 C     4         4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That's beautiful Quinten! Thank you! I wanted to ask you if I could change the NA value after specifying the row and column dimensions of x=NA meaning [1,2]

Comment: @LDT, what I think you're asking about is `df[1,2] <- "Yes"`, but since you're using a `tibble(.)`, the answer is "No", since tibbles are smart enough to not inadvertently change the class of a column. If you first do `df[,2] <- as.character(df[,2])` you can then do `df[1,2] <- "Yes"` without error. One could also do `mutate(x = if_else(row_number() == 1, "Yes", x))` (class notwithstanding). But that begs the question ... why are you trying to do things in a more austere, error-prone way?

Answer (score 5):

Since you already have answers in `dplyr`, I'll offer solutions in base R and `data.table`.

Base R -

```
df$x[is.na(df$x) & df$genes == "A"] <- "Yes"
```

`data.table` requires explicit changing the columns to character instead of implicit type conversion like in base R.

```
library(data.table)
df$x <- as.character(df$x)
setDT(df)[is.na(x) & genes == "A", x := "Yes"]
df

#   genes    x  y
#1:     A  Yes NA
#2:     B <NA>  3
#3:     C    4  4
```

Answer (score 4):

Quinten's answer is the simplest. I offer an alternative that is more defensive and declarative. (Translation: when I look at code that I wrote 6+ months ago, I often scratch my head wondering why certain things happen. Because of this, I tend to be a bit more "declarative" in certain steps to remind future-me of some steps.)

Background: `ifelse` is not class safe, it does not fail/warn when the classes of `yes=` and `no=` are not the same. (It also silently dumps some object classes, c.f., [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272.))
Examples:

```r
ifelse(c(T,T), 1, "A")
# [1] 1 1
ifelse(c(T,F), 1, "A")
# [1] "1" "A"
ifelse(c(T,F), Sys.Date(), 1+Sys.Date())
# [1] 19443 19444
ifelse(c(T,F), Sys.time(), 1+Sys.time())
# [1] 1679933419 1679933420
```

`dplyr::if_else` will fail since the classes are not the same, and this is good: it protects the user from unknowingly changing the class of the object. It requires that the user enforce this internally,

```r
df %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(is.na(x) & genes == 'A', 'Yes', x))
# Error in `mutate()`:
# ! Problem while computing `x = if_else(is.na(x) & genes == "A", "Yes", x)`.
# Caused by error in `if_else()`:
# ! `false` must be a character vector, not a double vector.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
df %>%
  mutate(
    x = as.character(x),
    x = if_else(is.na(x) & genes == 'A', 'Yes', x)
  )
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   genes x         y
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A     Yes      NA
# 2 B     <NA>      3
# 3 C     4         4
```

(We might have used `as.character(x)` directly within the `if_else` as well.)

FYI, `coalesce` is also useful here, though because of the dependency on `genes` it cannot fully replace:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    x = as.character(x), 
    x = if_else(genes == 'A', coalesce(x, 'Yes'), x)
  )
```

The advantage of `coalesce` is when there is no `genes` condition, where it might instead look as simple as `x = coalesce(x, "Yes")`.