# Zigzagging across rows per group?

Tags: sql, r

General Question on conversion between SQL and R

I am starting with this sample dataset:

```
start = structure(list(id = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 222L, 222L, 222L
), year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L),
col2 = c("A", "BB", "A", "C", "D", "EE", "F"), col3 = c(242L,
213L, 233L, 455L, 11L, 444L, 123L), col4 = c(1213L, 5959L,
9988L, 4242L, 333L, 1232L, 98L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-7L))
```

This is what I want to do in R:

```
 library(dplyr)

end <- start %>%
mutate(year_end = lead(year),
     col2_end = lead(col2),
     col3_end = lead(col3),
     col4_end = lead(col4)) %>%
mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_end")), ~ifelse(is.na(.), "END", .)) %>%
rename(year_start = year,
     col2_start = col2,
     col3_start = col3,
     col4_start = col4)
```

Now I try using SQL:

```
# my attempt to solve the problem
CREATE TABLE end AS
SELECT
id,
year AS year_start,
LEAD(year) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS year_end,
col2 AS col2_start,
LEAD(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS col2_end,
col3 AS col3_start,
LEAD(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS col3_end,
col4 AS col4_start,
LEAD(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS col4_end
FROM start;
```

Is this code doing the same thing as the R?

In the past, I have normally done this kind of in R, but I have my data on an SQL Server and am trying to optimize this code for larger datasets.

I think the code is correct, but I wanted to have a second set of eyes inspect this code for any possible problems. Anyone see any issues?

Comment: are you intentionally corrupting your integers? all of your `_end` variables are strings, which defeats the implied assumptions of variable class. (_Yes_, this can be reversed, but (1) not while retaining your special `"END"` indicator, and (2) it's safe _here_ but there are conditions where it will not be safe. It's far better to be explicit and safe with your data conversions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they doing the same thing? *No.* A few reasons:

1. In your SQL code, you have `partition by id`, and the equivalent in dplyr is `group_by(id)`, which you have omitted.
2. Your data has integers in it, but you are silently converting (corrupting) them to `character` by using `base::ifelse(., ., "END")`. It is bad-practice to allow R to silently cast to a different class, especially if downstream expects things to be integers. If you expect all of your fields to be strings, then I suggest you explicitly convert them to strings *first*.

   For this, my code below will retain the `integer` class until the end, and you can optionally choose to change them to strings with the last `mutate(..)`.

   Unless you know you strictly *need* the `"END"` string literal, I suggest it might be better to either use `NA` or some other number-like sentinel value, e.g., `Inf`. It depends heavily on how you're using it.
3. In your R code, you replace nulls (`NA`s) with `"END"`, and you don't attempt this in SQL. The right SQL verb is `COALESCE` after `CAST`ing the data to `varchar` (or `char` or ...).

FYI, `mutate_at` has been superseded for a while, I recommend you shift to `across`.

Below are the updated code blocks.

### dplyr

```r
start %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ lead(.), .names = "{.col}_end")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~ paste0(., "_start"), .cols = -c(id, ends_with("_end")))
# # A tibble: 7 × 9
#      id year_start col2_start col3_start col4_start year_end col2_end col3_end col4_end
#   <int>      <int> <chr>           <int>      <int>    <int> <chr>       <int>    <int>
# 1   111       2010 A                 242       1213     2011 BB            213     5959
# 2   111       2011 BB                213       5959     2012 A             233     9988
# 3   111       2012 A                 233       9988     2013 C             455     4242
# 4   111       2013 C                 455       4242       NA <NA>           NA       NA
# 5   222       2018 D                  11        333     2019 EE            444     1232
# 6   222       2019 EE                444       1232     2020 F             123       98
# 7   222       2020 F                 123         98       NA <NA>           NA       NA
```

If you really need `"END"` to indicate end-of-group (instead of what appears to be a clear `NA` here), then add to that:

```r
... %>%
  mutate(across(matches("_(start|end)$"), ~ coalesce(as.character(.), "END")))
# # A tibble: 7 × 9
#      id year_start col2_start col3_start col4_start year_end col2_end col3_end col4_end
#   <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
# 1   111 2010       A          242        1213       2011     BB       213      5959    
# 2   111 2011       BB         213        5959       2012     A        233      9988    
# 3   111 2012       A          233        9988       2013     C        455      4242    
# 4   111 2013       C          455        4242       END      END      END      END     
# 5   222 2018       D          11         333        2019     EE       444      1232    
# 6   222 2019       EE         444        1232       2020     F        123      98      
# 7   222 2020       F          123        98         END      END      END      END
```

### SQL

Your initial code produces the same as the first code block above (preserving `integer` class). I'll add `tibble` at the end just to get its column-class hints, not that it adds anything else to this discussion:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
SELECT
  id,
  year AS year_start,
  LEAD(year) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS year_end,
  col2 AS col2_start,
  LEAD(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS col2_end,
  col3 AS col3_start,
  LEAD(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS col3_end,
  col4 AS col4_start,
  LEAD(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS col4_end
FROM start;") %>%
  tibble()
# # A tibble: 7 × 9
#      id year_start year_end col2_start col2_end col3_start col3_end col4_start col4_end
#   <int>      <int>    <int> <chr>      <chr>         <int>    <int>      <int>    <int>
# 1   111       2010     2011 A          BB              242      213       1213     5959
# 2   111       2011     2012 BB         A               213      233       5959     9988
# 3   111       2012     2013 A          C               233      455       9988     4242
# 4   111       2013       NA C          <NA>            455       NA       4242       NA
# 5   222       2018     2019 D          EE               11      444        333     1232
# 6   222       2019     2020 EE         F               444      123       1232       98
# 7   222       2020       NA F          <NA>            123       NA         98       NA
```

If you need SQL to *also* change your numbers to strings and use `"END"`, then

```r
sqldf::sqldf("SELECT
id,
CAST(year as varchar(8)) AS year_start,
COALESCE(CAST(LEAD(year) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) as VARCHAR(9)), 'END') AS year_end,
CAST(col2 as varchar(8)) AS col2_start,
COALESCE(CAST(LEAD(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) as VARCHAR(9)), 'END') AS col2_end,
CAST(col3 as varchar(8)) AS col3_start,
COALESCE(CAST(LEAD(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) as VARCHAR(9)), 'END') AS col3_end,
CAST(col4 as varchar(8)) AS col4_start,
COALESCE(CAST(LEAD(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) as VARCHAR(9)), 'END') AS col4_end
FROM start;") %>%
  tibble()
# # A tibble: 7 × 9
#      id year_start year_end col2_start col2_end col3_start col3_end col4_start col4_end
#   <int> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>   
# 1   111       2010 2011     A          BB              242 213            1213 5959    
# 2   111       2011 2012     BB         A               213 233            5959 9988    
# 3   111       2012 2013     A          C               233 455            9988 4242    
# 4   111       2013 END      C          END             455 END            4242 END     
# 5   222       2018 2019     D          EE               11 444             333 1232    
# 6   222       2019 2020     EE         F               444 123            1232 98      
# 7   222       2020 END      F          END             123 END              98 END
```

---

If you haven't inferred so far, I am a stickler for consistency of variable `class`: too many times I've made assumptions about the class of an object and been stymied when R silently cast the variable to string or such. `ifelse` is a common culprit for this, contrast `ifelse(c(T,T), 1, "A")` and `ifelse(c(T,F), 1, "A")`; it is also not class-safe in [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272).