# How to change a value from a column using ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement, replace

Not sure what am I missing here but `ifelse` is not changing a value as I would expect. I am trying to change a week value if the month and day meet a certain criteria. Instead I am getting `"FALSE"` where it should be `52`. Example below:

```
> a
   SampleDate year   month week day
1  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
2  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
3  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
4  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
5  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
6  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
7  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
8  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
9  2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
10 2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
11 2013-01-07 2013 January   02  07
12 2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
13 2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
14 2013-01-08 2013 January   02  31
15 2013-01-07 2013 January   02  07
16 2013-01-03 2013 January   01  31
> 
> ## "FALSE" should be 52
> with(a, ifelse(month == 'January' & day == 31, week == 52, week))
 [1] "01"    "02"    "02"    "01"    "01"    "02"    "02"    "01"    "01"   
[10] "02"    "02"    "01"    "01"    "FALSE" "02"    "FALSE"
```

### data

```
a <- structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(15710, 15713, 15713, 
15710, 15710, 15713, 15713, 15710, 15708, 15713, 15712, 15708, 
15708, 15713, 15712, 15708), class = "Date"), year = c("2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), month = c("January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January"), week = c("01", "02", "02", 
"01", "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", 
"02", "01"), day = c("05", "08", "08", "05", "05", "08", "08", 
"05", "03", "08", "07", "03", "03", "31", "07", "31")), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `week==52` seems out of place, and here is one great example of how "[`ifelse` is not class-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272) is breaking for you. This effectively says "if month is january and day is 31 then return a logical vector else return a character vector". Clearly not what should be happening.

Comment: `week==52` is filling the `yes=` argument, which means its values are returned when the `test=` (first) argument is true. If the `test=` vector were all `TRUE`, then the return value from this `ifelse` would be a `logical` vector. However, since at least one of the `test` conditions are false, the fact that `day` is a character string casts all of the return values to string, which means `TRUE` -> `"TRUE"` (or `"FALSE"`). Please explain what you _intend_ the `week==52` to really mean.

Comment: Because of this, btw, I suggest you switch from using `base::ifelse` to `dplyr::if_else`: it will fail but fail _unambiguously_ (more clearly) and explain why what you tried to do is likely a mistake. There are rare times when I think `ifelse` is adequate.

Comment: I want tne numeric value of week to be 52 if month is january and day is 31. Not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: The issue is that you were testing equality with `==`. You wanted to assign to week inside of `ifelse` *which cannot be done*, the assignment must be done using `=` (single) (or optionally `<-` if not inside `mutate`) and must be outside of the `ifelse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the value of `week`, based on the values of `month` and `day`.  Here's one way to do that:

```
library(dplyr)

a |> mutate(week = if_else(month == 'January' & day == 31, '52', week))

   SampleDate year   month week day
1  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
2  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
3  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
4  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
5  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
6  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
7  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
8  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
9  2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
10 2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
11 2013-01-07 2013 January   02  07
12 2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
13 2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
14 2013-01-08 2013 January   52  31
15 2013-01-07 2013 January   02  07
16 2013-01-03 2013 January   52  31
```

Note that because your values for `week` can begin with 0, they are characters and not integers. That's why you need `'52'` instead of the numeric value 52.

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid using `ifelse`** in this context, as it degrades performance significantly. You can instead subset with brackets and replace with operator `<-`, either directly

```
a$week[with(a, month == 'January' & day == 31)] <- 52
tail(a, 3)
#    SampleDate year   month week day
# 14 2013-01-08 2013 January   52  31
# 15 2013-01-07 2013 January   02  07
# 16 2013-01-03 2013 January   52  31
```

or using `within`.

```
within(a, week[month == 'January' & day == 31] <- 52)
#    SampleDate year   month week day
# ...
# 14 2013-01-08 2013 January   52  31
# 15 2013-01-07 2013 January   02  07
# 16 2013-01-03 2013 January   52  31
```

### Benchmark

```
set.seed(42)
a_big <- a[sample.int(nrow(a), 1e5, replace=TRUE), ]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  `$<-`=  {a_big$week[with(a_big, month == 'January' & day == 31)] <- 52; a_big},
  `[<-`=  {a_big[with(a_big, month == 'January' & day == 31), 'week'] <- 52; a_big},
  within= within(a_big, week[month == 'January' & day == 31] <- 52),
  replace=transform(a_big, week=replace(week, month == 'January' & day == 31, 52)),
  ifelse= transform(a_big, week=ifelse(month == 'January' & day == 31, 52, week)),
  check='equivalent'
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval  cld
#      $<-  3.001781  3.081027  3.365160  3.145184  3.226759   8.168592   100 a   
#      [<- 16.257779 16.576023 17.014410 16.722306 16.929968  22.539319   100  b  
#   within  3.241322  3.349472  3.644337  3.408018  3.492567   9.169648   100 a   
#  replace 19.235649 19.529915 20.830925 19.795184 20.622298  53.269445   100   c 
#   ifelse 91.503930 92.620180 95.014174 93.657719 97.400140 105.806779   100    d
```

---

*Data:*

```
a <- structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(15710, 15713, 15713, 
15710, 15710, 15713, 15713, 15710, 15708, 15713, 15712, 15708, 
15708, 15713, 15712, 15708), class = "Date"), year = c("2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), month = c("January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January"), week = c("01", "02", "02", 
"01", "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", 
"02", "01"), day = c("05", "08", "08", "05", "05", "08", "08", 
"05", "03", "08", "07", "03", "03", "31", "07", "31")), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you want to stay in base R:

```r
transform(a, week = ifelse(month == 'January' & day == 31, '52', week))
#>    SampleDate year   month week day
#> 1  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
#> 2  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
#> 3  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
#> 4  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
#> 5  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
#> 6  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
#> 7  2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
#> 8  2013-01-05 2013 January   01  05
#> 9  2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
#> 10 2013-01-08 2013 January   02  08
#> 11 2013-01-07 2013 January   02  07
#> 12 2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
#> 13 2013-01-03 2013 January   01  03
#> 14 2013-01-08 2013 January   52  31
#> 15 2013-01-07 2013 January   02  07
#> 16 2013-01-03 2013 January   52  31
```