# Replacing values based on values of 2 another columns

Tags: r

I have those 3 columns. There are some NA Values in "Basiswert". If there is an NA Value in "Basiwert" I want to replace it with the Basiswert form the same number, which occurs either in Column "D" or "E".  For example: In line 2 there is an NA in Value in Basiswert. This value must be replaced with USDCAD = 12442 from line 3 in Column E.

```
structure(list(D = c("12449", "12448", "12447", "12446", "12442", 
"12441", "12440", "12439", "12438", "12437"), E = c("0", "12442", 
"12442", "12430", "0", "12430", "12436", "12436", "12430", "12430"
), Basiswert = c("EURJPY", NA, "USDCAD", "EURAUD", "USDCAD", 
"EURAUD", NA, "GBPJPY", NA, "EURAUD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Edit:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(Basiswert = ifelse(is.na(Basiswert) == FALSE & 
D == E, Basiswert, NA))
```

Is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite clear about the question. Check if this works.

```
data %>%
  group_by(E) %>%
  mutate(Basiswert2 = ifelse(is.na(Basiswert), max(Basiswert, na.rm = T), Basiswert))
```

Comment: (1) `dplyr::if_else` is better than `base::ifelse` for a few reasons, though they are minor here. (2) This op can be done faster/simpler with `Basiswert2 = coalesce(Basiswert, max(Basiswert, na.rm=TRUE))`.

Answer (score 4):

Another base R solution:

```r
data$Basiswert2 <- ave(data$Basiswert, data$E, FUN = function(z) replace(z, is.na(z), max(z, na.rm = TRUE)))
data
#        D     E Basiswert Basiswert2
# 1  12449     0    EURJPY     EURJPY
# 2  12448 12442      <NA>     USDCAD
# 3  12447 12442    USDCAD     USDCAD
# 4  12446 12430    EURAUD     EURAUD
# 5  12442     0    USDCAD     USDCAD
# 6  12441 12430    EURAUD     EURAUD
# 7  12440 12436      <NA>     GBPJPY
# 8  12439 12436    GBPJPY     GBPJPY
# 9  12438 12430      <NA>     EURAUD
# 10 12437 12430    EURAUD     EURAUD
```

Since you said you wanted to group within `D` and `E`, I suggest that this can be a chain:

```r
data |>
  transform(Basiswert = ave(Basiswert, D, FUN = function(z) ifelse(is.na(z), na.omit(z)[1], z))) |>
  transform(Basiswert = ave(Basiswert, E, FUN = function(z) ifelse(is.na(z), na.omit(z)[1], z)))
#        D     E Basiswert
# 1  12449     0    EURJPY
# 2  12448 12442    USDCAD
# 3  12447 12442    USDCAD
# 4  12446 12430    EURAUD
# 5  12442     0    USDCAD
# 6  12441 12430    EURAUD
# 7  12440 12436    GBPJPY
# 8  12439 12436    GBPJPY
# 9  12438 12430    EURAUD
# 10 12437 12430    EURAUD
```

Both `ifelse(is.na(z), z, ..)` and `replace(z, is.na(z), ..)` are effectively the same here ... the only reason I'd shy away from `ifelse` is if your data is anything other than int/num/chr ... for instance, if you are using this logic on a date or timestamp, then `ifelse` [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272).

The use of `max(..)` for determining the replacement value is a bit of a hack for strings; it can emit warnings in some situations (it did for me here), whereas the use of `na.omit(z)[1]` will *always* return either the first non-`NA` value, or `NA` itself if none exist.

Note that this is a form of imputation, which is a good buzz-word for searching when looking for methods like this. In this case, we impute for a missing value by finding the first non-`NA` value, which is one way; with strings, I think the other popular ways for imputing values include: (a) random; (b) most-frequent; and (c) least-frequent, perhaps for balancing when multiple values are expected per group. Numerical imputation can bring in many other options, including mean, mode, median, min/max, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Base R Solution (in the sample data only values for E have been repeated so we can ignore D):

```
# Split-apply-combine by column E values: 
# res_df => data.frame
res_df <- data.frame(
  do.call(
    rbind,
    # For each E value: 
    lapply(
      with(df, split(df, E)),
      function(x){
        # If the first value in the vector is na:
        if(is.na(x$Basiswert[1])){
          # Resolve the first non na value: ir => vector length 1
          ir <- x$Basiswert[min(which(!(is.na(x$Basiswert))))]
          # Fill the first na value with first non-na value: 
          x$Basiswert[1] <- ir
        # Otherwise: 
        }else{
          # Do nothing: 
          invisible()
        } 
        # Fill the values down: x$Basiswert => vector
        x$Basiswert <- na.omit(x$Basiswert)[cumsum(!(is.na(x$Basiswert)))]
        # Return the data.frame: data.frame => env
        x
      }
    )
  ),
  row.names = NULL
)
```

Tidyverse solution considering D if D also needs to be considered:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(E) %>%
  fill(Basiswert, .direction = "downup") %>% 
  group_by(D) %>% 
  fill(Basiswert, .direction = "downup")
```

Input Data:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    D = c("12449", "12448", "12447", "12446", "12442", 
    "12441", "12440", "12439", "12438", "12437"), 
    E = c("0", "12442", 
    "12442", "12430", "0", "12430", "12436", "12436", "12430", "12430"
    ), 
    Basiswert = c("EURJPY", NA, "USDCAD", "EURAUD", "USDCAD", "EURAUD", NA, "GBPJPY", NA, "EURAUD")
  ), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L)
)
```

Comment: the fill option is interesting: Here we could do also a combination with `arrange`: `df %>% 
  arrange(E, Basiswert) %>% 
  fill(Basiswert, .direction = "down") %>% 
  arrange(desc(D))`

Comment: @TarJae your approach here works well and I'm guessing sorting using `arrange()` would be faster than `group_by()` partitioning ? Is `fill()` no longer commonly used in tidyverse land ?

Answer (score 0):

With the same logic of @Hann Shaw we could use also `replace`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Basiswert2 = replace(Basiswert, is.na(Basiswert), max(Basiswert, na.rm = TRUE)), .by=E)

     D     E Basiswert Basiswert2
1  12449     0    EURJPY     EURJPY
2  12448 12442      <NA>     USDCAD
3  12447 12442    USDCAD     USDCAD
4  12446 12430    EURAUD     EURAUD
5  12442     0    USDCAD     USDCAD
6  12441 12430    EURAUD     EURAUD
7  12440 12436      <NA>     GBPJPY
8  12439 12436    GBPJPY     GBPJPY
9  12438 12430      <NA>     EURAUD
10 12437 12430    EURAUD     EURAUD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
structure(list(D = c(12327, 12328, 12329, 12330, 12331, 12333, 
12334, 12335, 12336, 12337, 12338, 12339, 12340, 12343, 12345, 
12348, 12349, 12350, 12351, 12352), E = c(12310, 12310, 12326, 
12326, 12315, 12326, 0, 12324, 12324, 12334, 12334, 0, 12339, 
0, 0, 12345, 12345, 0, 12343, 12343), Basiswert = c("AUDCAD", 
"AUDCAD", "USDJPY", "USDJPY", "USDCAD", "USDJPY", "USDCHF", "USDCHF", 
"USDCHF", "USDCHF", "USDCHF", "USDCAD", NA, "USDCAD", "CADJPY", 
"CADJPY", "CADJPY", "USDCHF", "USDCAD", "USDCAD"), Einstieg = c(NA, 
0.89262, NA, 139.192, NA, NA, 0.9052, NA, 0.90834, NA, 0.90816, 
NA, NA, 1.362, 103.188, NA, 102.886, 0.9051, NA, 1.36504), Profit = c(33, 
NA, 34, NA, 68, 68, NA, 33, NA, 33, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 34, NA, 
NA, 33, NA), SL = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.91134, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.3684, 102.545, NA, NA, 0.91138, NA, NA), TP = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.89325, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.3504, 
104.35, NA, NA, 0.8933, NA, NA), Trader = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Trade by Jason\" ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Trade by Jason\" ", 
"Trade by Jason\" ", NA, NA, "Trade by Jason\" ", NA, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    E = c(0, 12310, 12315, 12324, 12326, 12334, 12339, 12343, 
    12345), .rows = structure(list(c(7L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 18L), 
        1:2, 5L, 8:9, c(3L, 4L, 6L), 10:11, 13L, 19:20, 16:17), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Manny thanks for your effort and solutions. However, it sadly did not work on the entire data set.