# R - how to assign night time GPS data (i.e data which crosses over midnight) the same start date?

Tags: r, gps, grouping, posixct

I have GPS tag data which is for over night locations only. This has been filtered from a main data set already which calculated day and night based on sunset and sunrise times. As all day locations have been removed, night could be classed as from 3pm to 10am to allow for seasonal changes and make sure all data points are included.

The data is currently formatted with normal dates and times, e.g. 2019-03-22 21:53:00 and 2019-03-23 02:46:00. However, this data is technically from the same night. I want to add a new column to my data frame in R which groups data per night (rather than on their 'true' date) and assigns the dates/times after midnight to that of the starting date. So with the two dates above, they'd both be 2019-03-22.

So far I have tried the following code but it's making mistakes and the output column is a number (17976) rather than a date:

```
# Convert DateAndTime column to POSIXct format
sample$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(sample$DateTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

# Extract date component
sample$Date <- as.Date(sample$DateTime)

# Assign the night date
sample$NightDate <- ifelse(hour(sample$DateTime) < 8,
                       sample$Date - days(1),
                       sample$Date)

# change NightDate from numbers (17976) back to a date
as.Date(sample$NightDate)

# error which occurs: Error in as.Date.numeric(GE.sample$NightDate) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Due to data protection I can't share much of my data, but here's an example of the DateTime column which I'm working off:

```
# DateTime Data set  
2019-03-22 00:34:00
2019-03-22 02:43:00
2019-03-22 04:56:00
2019-03-22 19:28:00
2019-03-22 21:53:00
2019-03-23 02:46:00
2019-03-23 20:32:00
2019-03-23 23:04:00
2019-03-24 01:40:00
2019-03-24 04:17:00
2019-03-24 19:34:00
2019-03-24 23:22:00
2019-03-25 02:03:00
2019-03-25 04:48:00
```

I'm quite new to R so any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: What qualifies as a “night”? ie 18:00-08:00? Also, could you edit your question to include your example data as reproducible code rather than an image? Good luck!

Comment: Also, the number that you code outputs is R’s “backend” interpretation of the date - run `as.Date(17976)` and you will see that it returns 2019-03-21 - so just wrap it - `as.Date(sample$NightDate)`

Comment: @jpsmith thank you for your comments and I have updated the question so hopefully it makes a little more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of problems here.

1. You call `as.Date(.)` but don't reassign it back to the frame. This may not be a problem yet because of your error (#2), but know that you need to do

   ```r
   sample$NightDate <- as.Date(...)
   ```
2. A number in date-objects is the number of days since an "origin". Most computing (I believe) including R uses `1970-01-01`, but Excel uses `1899-12-30`. R will not assume this for you (despite many people really wanting it to default to the "epoch" origin of `1970-01-01`), you need to specify it. Try

   ```r
   sample$NightDate <- as.Date(sample$NightDate, origin = "1970-01-01")
   ```

   It can be a date object `as.Date("1970-01-01")` or something that is unambiguously a date, as what I did above.
3. `ifelse` drops class, [it's a known thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272), unfortunately. You can avoid dropping the class by removing the `Date` object from inside of `ifelse`'s return values. Perhaps

   ```r
   sample$NightDate <- sample$DateTime - ifelse(hour(sample$DateTime) < 8, 86400, 0)
   ```

   where `86400` is the number of seconds in one day. (It should be noted that timestamp/`POSIXt` objects have units of `1 sec` and date/`Date` objects have units of `1 day`.

Bottom line, starting with just `DateTime` (as a `POSIXt` timestamp), you can get `NightDate` with

```r
sample |>
  transform(
    NightDate = as.Date(trunc(
      DateTime - ifelse(lubridate::hour(DateTime) < 8, 86400, 0),
      by = "days"))
  )
#               DateTime  NightDate
# 1  2019-03-22 00:34:00 2019-03-21
# 2  2019-03-22 02:43:00 2019-03-21
# 3  2019-03-22 04:56:00 2019-03-21
# 4  2019-03-22 19:28:00 2019-03-22
# 5  2019-03-22 21:53:00 2019-03-22
# 6  2019-03-23 02:46:00 2019-03-22
# 7  2019-03-23 20:32:00 2019-03-23
# 8  2019-03-23 23:04:00 2019-03-23
# 9  2019-03-24 01:40:00 2019-03-23
# 10 2019-03-24 04:17:00 2019-03-23
# 11 2019-03-24 19:34:00 2019-03-24
# 12 2019-03-24 23:22:00 2019-03-24
# 13 2019-03-25 02:03:00 2019-03-24
# 14 2019-03-25 04:48:00 2019-03-24
```

The `lubridate::hour` function is useful. If you aren't using `lubridate` for anything else and need to reduce your use of other packages, you can use `as.integer(format(DateTime, format="%H"))` or `as.POSIXlt(sample$DateTime)$hour`, both are identical in effect (though `lubridate::hour` has a "fancy" way to *render* on the console).

---

Date

```r
sample <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1553229240, 1553236980, 1553244960, 1553297280, 1553305980, 1553323560, 1553387520, 1553396640, 1553406000, 1553415420, 1553470440, 1553484120, 1553493780, 1553503680), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this, I have managed to almost get it working with your help as follows:

`# Convert DateAndTime column to POSIXct format
sample$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(sample$DateTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`

`# Assign the night date
sample$NightDate <- sample$Date - ifelse(hour(sample$DateTime) < 12, 86400, 0)`

`# Extract date component
sample$NightDay <- as.Date(sample$NightDate)`

However, all readings within the hour of midnight (00:00 to 01:00), are assigned a day too early. Is there an easy way to solve this or is it best to filter them out?

Comment: I apologize @CjC, there was a typo in the last code block, I've fixed, please try the updated code. (I forgot to compare against `< 8`, \*facepalm*). Also, though, I added a `trunc` since it appears there may have been "rounding" (up) somewhere.

Comment: This is all working perfectly now. Thank you very much for your help and for explaining it so clearly, it's very much appreciated!